# How do return both a variable result and a true/false in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

It sounds silly, but lets say my predicate largest/2 returns the largest element in a list...the output should look like this:

```
?- largest([1,2,3,4,5], X).
X = 5.
false.
```

I implemented largest, and it works like above except it doesn't output "false". How do I make it so it also outputs this "false." value? This is for an annoying assignment I have to finish. :(

Answer (score 9):

That extra `false.` or `No` just means that the person running the program asked to get all possible solutions for `X`, not just the first possible solution.

On most interactive Prolog interpreters, you check to see if there is another solution by pressing the semicolon (`;`) key.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like impossible, as if predicate fails, no binding of free variables happens, see

```
 ?- A=5.
A = 5.

 ?- A=5,false.
false.
```

however

```
 ?- A=5;false.
A = 5 ;
false.
```

To achieve this you should make your predicate "largest" non-deterministic. But to me this seems pretty silly.

Comment: s(X): if I follow the question to a T, this somewhat odd answer is **it**.  And it has great timing, too!

Answer (score 1):

If this was part of an assignment, it probably means that your predicate should not yield a second (possibly different) result after backtracking. Backtracking occurs if the user wants the next solution, often by pressing <kbd>;</kbd>. The interpreter often indicates that another solution is possible when it knows there are still paths not fully evaluated.

Suppose you had a predicate `foo/1` as follows:

```
foo(1).

foo(Bar) :-
   foo(Baz),
   Bar is Baz + 1.
```

If you ask `foo(Bar)`, the interpreter will respond with `Bar = 1`. After repeatedly pressing <kbd>;</kbd>, the interpreter will come back with `Bar = 2`, `Bar = 3` and so on.

In your example, finding the largest of a list, should be deterministic. Backtracking should not yield a different answer.

It's up to you to interpret the assignment to mean that you have to allow backtracking but have it fail, or that it would be all right to not even have it backtrack at all.

Comment: s(X): It's funny how even short specs lead to fundamentally opposite conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* something to the previous answers by [@aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271096), [@Xonix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271258), and [@SQB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36220973).

In this answer, we use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for expressing declarative integer arithmetics.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We define `largest/2` using the built-in predicate [`member/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member), library [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915), and the finite-domain constraint [`(#>=)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%23%3E%3D%29/2):

```
largest(Zs, X) :-
   member(X, Zs),            % X is a member of the list Zs
   maplist(#>=(X), Zs).      % all Z in Zs fulfill X #>= Z
```

Sample queries:

```
?- largest([1,2,3,4,5], X).
X = 5.

?- largest([1,2,3,4,5,4], X).
X = 5 ;
false.

?- largest([1,2,3,4,5,5], X).
X = 5 ;
X = 5.

?- largest([1,2,3,4,5,5,4], X).
X = 5 ;
X = 5 ;
false.

?- largest([A,B,C,D], X).
A = X, X#>=D, X#>=C, X#>=B ;
B = X, X#>=A, X#>=D, X#>=C ;
C = X, X#>=A, X#>=D, X#>=B ;
D = X, X#>=A, X#>=C, X#>=B.
```