# Prolog map procedure that applies predicate to list elements

Tags: prolog, map-function, meta-predicate

How do you write a Prolog procedure `map(List, PredName, Result)` that applies the predicate `PredName(Arg, Res)` to the elements of `List`, and returns the result in the list `Result`?

For example:

```
test(N,R) :- R is N*N.

?- map([3,5,-2], test, L).
L = [9,25,4] ;
no
```

Answer (score 53):

This is usually called `maplist/3` and is part of the [Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist). Note the different argument order!

```
:- meta_predicate(maplist(2, ?, ?)).

maplist(_C_2, [], []).
maplist( C_2, [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
   call(C_2, X, Y),
   maplist( C_2, Xs, Ys).
```

The different argument order permits you to easily nest several `maplist`-goals.

```
?- maplist(maplist(test),[[1,2],[3,4]],Rss).
   Rss = [[1,4],[9,16]].
```

`maplist` comes in different arities and corresponds to [the following constructs in functional languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29), but requires that all lists are of same length. Note that Prolog does not have the asymmetry between `zip`/`zipWith` and `unzip`. A goal `maplist(C_3, Xs, Ys, Zs)` subsumes both and even offers more general uses.

- `maplist/2` corresponds to `all`
- `maplist/3` corresponds to `map`
- `maplist/4` corresponds to `zipWith` but also `unzip`
- `maplist/5` corresponds to `zipWith3` and `unzip3`
- ...

Comment: +1. In modern Prologs, you'll find `maplist` somewhere in the library.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: Please refer to [tag:meta-predicate] for more!

Comment: I do not believe that the SWI-Prolog version of maplist/3 corresponds to map anymore. It seems to be `all` but delivers the input in pairs from both lists. Is there a predicate that has the same functionality as `map`?

Comment: SWI has `maplist/2/3/4/5`. And, no SWI **does not** "deliver input in pairs", except you use such a predicate in the 1st argument.  Please give a **concrete** example, where you think map cannot be expressed with `maplist`. Except for cases where the lists are of different length.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused by the documentation. [maplist/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3), "As maplist/2, operating on pairs of elements from two lists" implies to me (a novice prolog programmer) that `maplist/3` has the same functionality as `maplist/2` which is `all` but with different inputs to the first argument. This resulted in me ignoring maplist/3 and finding/writing my own map predicate.

Comment: @bennyty: That documentation is infact a bit misleading.

Comment: @false I came to the same conclusion. could you explain how `maplist/3` is _not_ `all`? I get:
`?- maplist(=, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]).
true.` not `[true, true, true]`, whereas `convlist/3` seems to be exactly `map`.

Comment: @ErikKaplun: Consider `As = [1,2,3], maplist(`[`succ`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#succ)`, As, Bs)`. Where do you see an `all` in here? That's a typical `map`.

Comment: @ErikKaplun: Now you talk about `maplist/2` instead of `maplist/3`. See above...

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right, how embarrassing! Apologies, my Prolog-eye is still young! But then I should add that `maplist/3` is also `all`, but can be used like `map`, or even better, `map` and `all` are the same thing in Prolog, due to predicates/relations being more general than functions.