# Prolog length of a list

Tags: list, prolog

How can I calculate the length of a list

```
?- size_sub([[b,a,g], [9,3,7,4], [6]],  X).
X = [3, 4, 1].

?- size_sub([[c,g,e,w], [7]],  X).
X = [4, 1].

?- size_sub([],  X).
X = [].
```

Comment: is that last one correct? to be consistent wouldn't that be `size_sub([[]],X).` or `size_sub([],X)` the answer would be `[]`

Answer (score 6):

Ok you need to start with the base case which is the last answer

so `size_sub([],X).` is true if `X=[]` so first you write that as a rule.

```
size_sub([],[]).
```

Then you need to do the inductive step a list that is one longer than the previous.  I am going to assume that you have a size/2 function for determining the size of a single list (if not please comment).

So the inductive step is going to operate on the length of the first parameter so N->N+1.  We would represent this by striping off the head of the list syntax will be `[H|T]` now the second parameter (your answer) is going to be the length of H with the result of calling size_sub on T.  As we cannot specify rules in the parameters in the header we will use N to represent the length of H and T2 to represent the result of size_sub on T.

So the first part of the rule becomes `size_sub([H|T],[N|T2]):-`

now we follow it with the predicates that will assert the values for N and T2.

```
size(H,N),
size_sub(T,T2).
```

putting that all together you get

```
size_sub([],[]).

size_sub([H|T],[N|T2]):-
    size(H,N),
    size_sub(T,T2).
```

size/2 is a far simpler case and following the same process of base + inductive you should be able to create the rules for it.  Please comment if you need further help.

** EDIT - Request for size/2 definition **

To define size/2

Start with the base case, the empty list has a size of 0.

```
size([],0).
```

Now the inductive step.  The size of list of length(N+1) is the size of a list of length(N). So lets define our list as `[_|T]` I've defined the list using _ to represent the head because we never use it so we can just use the anonymous variable. Lets use N to represent the length of T, and M to be N+1.

so

size([_|T],M):-

now lets define N

```
  size(T,N),
```

and finally assert that M is equal to N + 1

```
  M is N+1.
```

so putting everything together

```
size([],0).

size([_|T],N):-
    size(T,M),
    N is M+1.

size_sub([],[]).

size_sub([H|T],[N|T2]):-
    size(H,N),
    size_sub(T,T2).
```

Comment: I don't know how to create size/2

Answer (score 6):

To map [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) over a list of lists, we can use the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) like this:

```
size_sub(Xss,Ls):-
    maplist(length,Xss,Ls).
```