# Testing if all lists in a list have the same length

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to learn more about lists in Prolog, especially lists within a list. So I want to write a predicate to determine if the lists in a list are equal. So if I did this

```
?- equalLists([[a,b,c],[1,2,3],[d,4,e],[5,6]]).
false
```

So I'm trying to check each list to see if it is has the same length as the previous list. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Peteris's solution is unnecessarily complex. You can do it like this:

```
equal_lengths([]).
equal_lengths([[]]).
equal_lengths([[_|_]]).
equal_lengths([X,Y|Rest]) :- 
  length(X, Len), 
  length(Y, Len), 
  equal_lengths([Y|Rest]).
```

Think inductively. I'm asserting that the length of the empty list and a list of one list are "equal" (there are no/just one other to compare to). Then I say if the length of the first item equals the length of the second item, as long as the lengths of the second item and the rest match we are good.

**Note:** we're not explicitly saying that the length of X and Y is the same with some kind of equality test. We're letting Prolog handle that for us, by simply declaring that the length of X and Y is Len. So if the length of Y doesn't unify with the length of X, the predicate will fail.

**Reversing the process**

So, to write a predicate to determine if none of the lists have the same length we must observe that this time we will have to keep track of which lengths have been seen so far to check against. We must compare each list's length to all the preceeding list lengths to determine inequality. So this time our initial case will create the initial list of lengths and defer processing to another predicate like so:

```
unequal_lengths(X) :- unequal_lengths(X, []).
```

Now we again begin with similar base cases:

```
unequal_lengths([], _).
unequal_lengths([[]], _).
unequal_lengths([[_|_]], _).
```

Things get interesting when we have an actual list:

```
unequal_lengths([X|Rest], Lengths) :-
  length(X, Len),
  \+ member(Len, Lengths),
  unequal_lengths(Rest, [Len|Lengths]).
```

So we're calculating the length of this list, then asserting that this is not a length we have seen before with the handy member predicate, then passing this length along with the rest along to the remainder of the list.

**Addendum: unequal w/ forall**

Inspired by the other answers, you can implement unequal_lengths in a higher-order fashion like so:

```
unequal_lengths(Lists) :-
  findall(Len, (member(X, Lists), length(X, Len)), Lengths),
  forall(select(Len, Lengths, Remaining), \+ member(Len, Remaining)).
```

If you think about it, this corresponds quite closely to a formal logic expression of the problem: for every list length, there does not exist an element of the remaining list lengths corresponding to this one.

Comment: Your second case should be `equal_lengths([[_|_]]).` - you don't want any list of non-lists to succeed.

Comment: Just realised we need another base case, `equal_lengths([[]]).`

Comment: I have another simple question, how would I reverse that. Like if I wanted to make sure none of the lists were equal.

Comment: @NickBarnes In that case maybe `[X]` isn't so bad.

Comment: @azur3al that's a harder task, because it isn't sufficient for each list just to be inequal to the next one; instead, each list has to be checked against all the others. Which is a clue as to how to proceed.

Comment: @azur3al I've added the opposite predicate to the answer

Comment: @Daniel Lyons Thanks a lot. It was really bugging me that I couldn't get it to work but I see what I was doing wrong. :)

Comment: Inverting logic is not always straightforward with Prolog. :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

First, we define some standard higher order relations, `map` and `fold`. This requires the built-in `call` predicate. One could just define `maxlist` etc. as one-offs, but this should be more illuminating.

The idea is to get a list of lengths and then compare if the maximum number in the list is equal to the minimum.

```
maplist(_, [], []).
maplist(P, [X | Y], [A | B]) :-
  call(P, X, A),
  maplist(P, Y, B).

max(A, B, M) :- A <  B, M = B.
max(A, B, M) :- A >= B, M = A.

min(A, B, M) :- B <  A, M = B.
min(A, B, M) :- B >= A, M = A.

fold(_, [X], X).
fold(P, [X, Y], R) :- call(P, X, Y, R).
fold(P, [X, Y | Z], R) :-
  fold(P, [Y | Z], NR),
  call(P, NR, X, R).

maxlist(L, M) :- fold(max, L, M).

minlist(L, M) :- fold(min, L, M).

equallists(L) :-
  maplist(length, L, Lengths),
  maxlist(Lengths, Max),
  minlist(Lengths, Min),
  Max == Min.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a lot more complicated than I thought it would be.

Comment: It really isn't necessary to reimplement Haskell in Prolog to write Prolog. You can definitely do it without all this.

Comment: The predicates @Peteris defines have been present in Prolog system already in the beginning 1980s. E.g. the DEC-10 Prolog library contained maplist/3 at least since 1983. So it is not Haskell that is reimplemented here. But yes, functional languages have been the source of inspiration for it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll rewrite the Peteris answer (+1) using SWI-Prolog builtins [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29) and [aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%284,%27A.1.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29):

```
equallists(L) :-
  maplist(length, L, Lengths),
  aggregate(max(T), member(T, Lengths), N),
  aggregate(min(T), member(T, Lengths), N).
```

Done!

Even simpler, using [lambda](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) (here the [doc page](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord)) to adjust arguments order:

```
:- [lambda].

equallists([H|T]) :-
  length(H, N),
  maplist(\L^length(L, N), T).
```

Variazione sul tema (this should be minimal):

```
equallists([H|T]) :-
  length(H, N),
  forall(member(L, T), length(L, N)).
```

As @false noted, when T is not ground, the test can fail. A possible correction:

```
equallists([H|T]) :-
  length(H, N),
  forall(member(L, T), (nonvar(L), length(L, N))).
```

forall/2, that I think could be described as a form of failure driven loop, can be easily misusedit.

OTOH, every control flow construct in Prolog can be difficult to use properly, and this is perhaps the main cause of the scarce popularity of the language.

Comment: This is great info. I haven't seen the lambda library before.

Comment: Can you supply a link to more info about lambda? It doesn't seem to be included in my SWI-Prolog distribution and I don't see anything on the site about it.

Comment: I've placed the link in the post. I have to say that is rather easy misuse that code...

Comment: @chac, I do not agree with your last variation using `forall/2`. It incorrectly succeeds for `equallists([[],Nil]), Nil = [_].`

Comment: @false. And that based on aggregate doesn't terminate! The only working seems the lambda based.

Comment: @chac: A comment on the "scarce popularity": Your example is quite illustrative in this respect. As long as you stick to the pure monotonic Prolog you do not have such problems. It is only if you take constructs as `forall/2`, `nonvar/1` that you do not use accompanied with clean errors that you get those problems.  E.g., the `nonvar/1` will make `equallists([[],Nil])`. fail, but is should succeed.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that takes advantage of the first-argument indexing found in most Prolog systems to avoid spurious choice-points in most (but not all) cases:

```
equal_lengths([]).
equal_lengths([L1| Ls]) :-
    equal_lengths_aux(Ls, L1).

equal_lengths_aux([], _).
equal_lengths_aux([L2| Ls], L1) :- 
    equal_length(L1, L2), 
    equal_lengths_aux(Ls, L2).

equal_length([], []).
equal_length([_| Tail1], [_| Tail2]) :-
    equal_length(Tail1, Tail2).
```

Some sample queries:

```
| ?- equal_lengths([]). 

yes
| ?- equal_lengths([[]]).

yes
| ?- equal_lengths([_]). 

yes
| ?- equal_lengths([[],_]).

yes
| ?- equal_lengths([_,[]]).

true ? ;

no
| ?- equal_lengths([L1,L2]).

L1 = []
L2 = [] ? ;

L1 = [_]
L2 = [_] ? ;

L1 = [_,_]
L2 = [_,_] ? 

...
| ?- equal_lengths([[a,b,c],[1,2,3],[d,4,e],[5,6]]).

no
| ?- equal_lengths([[a,b,c],[1,2,3],[d,4,e],[5,6,7],L]).

L = [_,_,_]

yes
| ?- equal_lengths([L1,[_,_],L3]).                      

L1 = [_,_]
L3 = [_,_] ? ;

no

| ?- equal_lengths([L1,[_,_|_],L3]).

L1 = [_,_]
L3 = [_,_] ? ;

L1 = [_,_,_]
L3 = [_,_,_] ? ;

L1 = [_,_,_,_]
L3 = [_,_,_,_] ? ;

...
```

We only get a **spurious** choice-point (i.e. a choice-point that doesn't lead to a solution) when the first element is unbound and there are bound list elements. If no list element is bound to a **finite** list, the predicate generates solutions where the list length keeps growing as illustrated in the sample queries.

Comment: Best termination property so far! Just out of curiosity: Do you think that also `equal_lengths([_,_,[]])` and similar may terminate?

Comment: I can make changes that allows this goal to terminate but then a similar issue will show up elsewhere. I have not found yet a better solution that terminates for this goal and all similar goals (without any regressions). I doubt such a solution exists but I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I am not sure about it at all - maybe some diagonalization-trick might work.

Comment: See my second solution. It fixes this particular case and also `equal_lengths([L])`, which must generate `L` with increasing length when asking for the next solution.

Answer (score 2):

Follows a second solution with better termination properties compared with my first attempt. The main idea is at each traversal of the list of lists, we drop a single element from every list.

```
equal_lengths([]).
equal_lengths([L1| Ls]) :-
    pick(L1, Ls, Rs),
    equal_lengths(Rs).

pick([], Ls, []) :-
    all_empty(Ls).
pick([_| R1], Ls, [R1| Rs]) :-
    pick(Ls, Rs).

pick([], []).
pick([[_|R1]| Ls], Rs) :-
    pick([_|R1], Ls, Rs).

all_empty([]).
all_empty([[]| Rs]) :-
    all_empty(Rs).
```

The problematic case @false mentioned in a comment to my first solution was:

```
| ?- equal_lengths([_,_,[]]).

true ? ;

no
```

It's more clear, however, that we get the single correct solution if we don't use anonymous variables:

```
| ?- equal_lengths([L1,L2,[]]).

L1 = []
L2 = [] ? ;

no
```

All the previous sample queries in my first solution pose no problems. One query in particular is worth mention, as it wrongly only provided a single solution instead of generating solutions in the previous attempt. Now it works as expected:

```
| ?- equal_lengths([L]).

L = [] ? ;

L = [_] ? ;

L = [_,_] ? ;

L = [_,_,_] ? ;

...
```

Can anyone find a sample query leading to trouble with this solution?

Comment: Good idea! I like it.

Comment: s(X). OTOH: `equal_lengths([[_],[_,_|_]|_]).` now loops, whereas your first version correctly failed. So you are trading some cases of termination for other cases.

Comment: @false Good catch! Looping results from the input being an open list. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

The next dish on my menu: the [baroque](http://hackersdictionary.com/html/entry/baroque.html) [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) [prolog-coroutining](/questions/tagged/prolog-coroutining) hodgepodge.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

samelength_of(N,Xss) :- maplist(length_of__lazy(N),Xss).

length_of__lazy(N,Xs) :-
   N #>= 0,
   (  nonvar(N)
   -> length(Xs,N)
   ;  var(Xs)
   -> when((nonvar(Xs);nonvar(N)), length_of__lazy(N,Xs))
   ;  Xs = []
   -> N = 0
   ;  Xs = [_|Xs0]
   -> N0 + 1 #= N,
      length_of__lazy(N0,Xs0)
   ;  throw(error(type_error(list,Xs),length_of__lazy/2))
   ).

my_indomain(N) :-
   fd_inf(N,I),
   (  N #= I
   ;  N #> I, my_indomain(N)
   ).
```

Some sample queries:

```
?- Xss = [As,Bs,Cs], As=[], samelength_of(N,Xss).
N = 0, Xss = [[],[],[]], As = [], Bs = [], Cs = [].

?- Xss = [As,Bs,Cs], samelength_of(N,Xss), As=[].
N = 0, Xss = [[],[],[]], As = [], Bs = [], Cs = [].
```

Some more? Want to try the flounder?

```
?- samelength_of(N,[As,Bs,Cs]).
N in 0..sup,
when((nonvar(As);nonvar(N)), length_of__lazy(N,As)),
when((nonvar(Bs);nonvar(N)), length_of__lazy(N,Bs)),
when((nonvar(Cs);nonvar(N)), length_of__lazy(N,Cs)).
```

Flounder is not your taste? *No problemo!*

```
?- samelength_of(N,[As,Bs,Cs]), my_indomain(N).
N = 0, As = [],            Bs = [],            Cs = []            ;
N = 1, As = [_A1],         Bs = [_B1],         Cs = [_C1]         ;
N = 2, As = [_A1,_A2],     Bs = [_B1,_B2],     Cs = [_C1,_C2]     ;
N = 3, As = [_A1,_A2,_A3], Bs = [_B1,_B2,_B3], Cs = [_C1,_C2,_C3] ...
```

Comment: Given all this complexity, `samelength_of(N, [[_|L],L]).` still flounders/loops

Comment: @false. I'm sorry! Where was my mind? Had a stack overflow, probably.

Answer (score 1):

With the right tools---the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) and [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord)---all we need is one line:

```
?- Xss = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4,5]], maplist(N+\Xs^length(Xs,N),Xss).
false.

?- Xss = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]],   maplist(N+\Xs^length(Xs,N),Xss).
N = 2.
```

`(+\)/2` helps us state that `N` is free, so we use **the same `N`** as the length of each `Xs` in `Xss`.

Comment: Doesn't terminate for `Xss = [_,[]]` (as all the other solutions)

Answer (score -2):

I find the only acceptable solution to be chac's last one, for sake of completness I'd add the empty list handling though :

```
equalLengths([]).
equalLengths([Head|Tail]) :-
    length(Head, Length),
    forall(member(List, Tail), length(List, Length)).
```

Comment: well simply because as the prolog implementation used is specified, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Not to say yours is incorrect, it does is correct and quite simple. Chac's last one is better though.

Comment: He must have added that one later, I thought you were referring to the `lamdba` variant. Which is cool, but isn't as useful to the beginner as his `forall` variant.

Comment: @Mog, this solution is incorrect. Please refer to chac's answer.

Comment: I get your point but I don't see how the success you mention is incorrect tbh.

Comment: @Mog: It is incorrect, because the list `[[],[_]]` contains two lists of different length.  Upon success of `equallists([[],Nil])`, `Nil` has to be `[]`. Any other value is incorrect.