# Prolog - Multiply a list with an element results with a weird tail?

Tags: lambda, prolog, swi-prolog

I want to multiply two lists, where I take the left list and multiply it by each element of 
the right list.

For example:

```
?- multLists([3,4,2], [4,7,8], R).
R = [[12,16,8],[21,28,14],[24,32,16]].
```

For that I wrote a helper predicate that takes a list and multiplies it 
by a single scalar:

```
multListElem([], _, _).
multListElem([H|T], Result, Elem) :- 
    multListElem(T, W, Elem),
    Z is H*Elem,
    Result = [Z|W].
```

But now, when I run `?- multListElem([1,2,3], X, 3).`
I get:

```
1 ?- multListElem([1,2,3], X, 3).
X = [3, 6, 9|_G1840].
```

What is that weird tail `_G1840`?

Comment: Please do not change your question! It renders the existing answers useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug is here: `multListElem([],_,_)`.  When the first list is empty, the result is empty, so you must write `multListElem([],[],_).`

When you work with lists, you can use functional idioms like 
[maplist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915):

```
multLists(L1, L2, R) :-
    maplist(mult_one_list(L1), L2, R).

mult_one_list(L1, Elem, R) :-
    maplist(mult_2_numbers(Elem), L1, R).

mult_2_numbers(V1, V2, R) :-
    R is V1 * V2.
```

[`maplist`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist) applies the first argument to each element of each list (passed to it as an argument).

Answer (score 3):

your base case leave uninstantiated the tail: change to

```
multListElem([],[],_).
```

and it will work.

@Joel76 already addressed your problem, and exposed a better approach using maplist. If you have lambda.pl available here is a compact formula solving the problem

```
?- maplist(\A^B^maplist(\X^Y^(Y is X*A), [3,4,2], B), [4,7,8], R).
R = [[12, 16, 8], [21, 28, 14], [24, 32, 16]].
```

**edit** of course the proper interface would be

```
multLists(L1, L2, R) :-
    maplist(\A^B^maplist(\X^Y^(Y is X*A), L1, B), L2, R).
```

The second bug that @false pointed it's difficult to understand but easy to fix:

```
multLists(L1, L2, R) :-
    maplist(\A^maplist(\X^Y^(Y is X*A), L1), L2, R).
```

The first bug I would call a feature: it's *very* useful that lambda works with the closure, and `A` **is** declared then... Just my 2 cents...

Comment: A must be declared ; and B can be removed via partial application!

Comment: @false: it's great to learn Prolog with a *great* teacher. Thanks!

Comment: Use in place of Y is X*A rather than Y = X*A. And use as lists [A,B,C] and [X,Y,Z]: Thus, no ground terms...