# Prolog substitution

Tags: replace, prolog, substitution

How can I replace a list with another list that contain the variable to be replaced. for example

```
rep([x, d, e, z, x, z, p], [x=z, z=x, d=c], R).
R = [z, c, e, x, z, x, p]
```

the x to z and z doesn't change after it has been replaced.

so far I did only the one without the list

```
rep([], _, []).
rep(L1, H1=H2, L2) :-
   rep(L1, H1, H2, L2).

rep([],_,_,[]).
rep([H|T], X1, X2, [X2|L]) :-
   H=X1,
   rep(T,X1,X2,L),
   !.
rep([H|T],X1,X2,[H|L]) :-
   rep(T,X1,X2,L).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your code rather confused. For one thing, you have `rep/3` and `rep/4`, but none of them have a list in the second position where you're passing the list of variable bindings. `H1=H2` cannot possibly match a list, and that's the only `rep/3` clause that examines the second argument. If this is a class assignment, it looks like you're a little bit behind and I'd suggest you spend some time on the previous material.

The solution is simpler than you'd think:

```
rep([], _, []).
rep([X|Xs], Vars, [Y|Rest]) :-    member(X=Y, Vars), rep(Xs, Vars, Rest).
rep([X|Xs], Vars, [X|Rest]) :- \+ member(X=_, Vars), rep(Xs, Vars, Rest).
```

We're using `member/2` to find a "variable binding" in the list (in quotes because these are atoms and not true Prolog variables). If it's in the list, Y is the replacement, otherwise we keep using X. And you see this has the desired effect:

```
?- rep([x, d, e, z, x, z, p], [x=z, z=x, d=c], R).
R = [z, c, e, x, z, x, p] ;
false.
```

This could be made somewhat more efficient using "or" directly (and save us a choice point):

```
rep([], _, []).
rep([X|Xs], Vars, [Y|Ys]) :- 
  (member(X=Y, Vars), ! ; X=Y), 
  rep(Xs, Vars, Ys).
```

See:

```
?- rep([x, d, e, z, x, z, p], [x=z, z=x, d=c], R).
R = [z, c, e, x, z, x, p].
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use SWI-Prolog, with module lambda.pl found there : http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl you can write :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

rep(L, Rep, New_L) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^(member(X=Z, Rep)
              ->  Y = Z
              ;   Y = X), L, New_L).
```

Answer (score 1):

You should attempt to keep the code simpler than possible:

```
rep([], _, []).
rep([X|Xs], Vs, [Y|Ys]) :-
   ( memberchk(X=V, Vs) -> Y = V ; Y = X ),
   rep(Xs, Vs, Ys).
```

Of course, note the idiomatic way (thru memberchk/2) to check for a variable value.

Still yet a more idiomatic way to do: transforming lists it's a basic building block in several languages, and Prolog is no exception:

```
rep(Xs, Vs, Ys) :- maplist(repv(Vs), Xs, Ys).
repv(Vs, X, Y) :- memberchk(X=V, Vs) -> Y = V ; Y = X .
```

Comment: I admit I had to chuckle when I read you wrote: "You should attempt to keep the code **simpler** than possible". Made my day:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could proceed using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915).

First, we try to find a single `Key` in a list of pairs `K-V`.
An extra argument reifies search success.

```
pairs_key_firstvalue_t([]       ,_  ,_    ,false).
pairs_key_firstvalue_t([K-V|KVs],Key,Value,Truth) :-
   if_(K=Key,
       (V=Value, Truth=true),
       pairs_key_firstvalue_t(KVs,Key,Value,Truth)).
```

Next, we need to handle "not found" cases:

```
assoc_key_mapped(Assoc,Key,Value) :-
   if_(pairs_key_firstvalue_t(Assoc,Key,Value),
       true,
       Key=Value).
```

Last, we put it all together using the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915):

```
?- maplist(assoc_key_mapped([x-z,z-x,d-c]), [x,d,e,z,a,z,p], Rs).
Rs = [z,c,e,x,a,x,p].                       % OK, succeeds deterministically
```

Comment: looks like a bad abstraction: There might be other cases where the first value is of interest, not only when equality applies.

Comment: @false. How about building `pairs_key_firstvalue_t` on top of that "find-first-item-in-list-suchthat" idiom instead?

Comment: @j4nbur53. No, it's not a function, but a predicate that an extra argument (`_t` is short for `_truth` / `_truthvalue`) to reflect success/failure into the atoms `true`/`false`. This argument is then used subsequently by `if_/3` for steering the control flow in the right direction.

Comment: @j4nbur53. cool links... I did not quite get the last sentence of your previous comment, please elaborate! p_t may be used with T (the extra argument) being bound or unbound. What you wrote about p_t being the same as a function f_t gets right to the heart of the matter: in p_t(...,T) the var T *eventually* gets uniquely determined when the instantiation is sufficient. However, this may not be so if p_t is used with non-ground data, so we use don't-know style nondeterminism then (and only then) in order to stay complete.

Answer (score 1):

Let's improve [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31586966/4609915) by moving the "recursive part" into [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `find_first_in_t/4`:

```
:- meta_predicate find_first_in_t(2,?,?,?).
find_first_in_t(P_2,X,Xs,Truth) :-
   list_first_suchthat_t(Xs,X,P_2,Truth).

list_first_suchthat_t([]    ,_, _ ,false).
list_first_suchthat_t([E|Es],X,P_2,Truth) :-
   if_(call(P_2,E),
       (E=X,Truth=true),
       list_first_suchthat_t(Es,X,P_2,Truth)).
```

To fill in the "missing bits and pieces", we define `key_pair_t/3`:

```
key_pair_t(Key,K-_,Truth) :-
   =(Key,K,Truth).
```

Based on `find_first_in_t/4` and `key_pair_t/3`, we can write `assoc_key_mapped/3` like this:

```
assoc_key_mapped(Assoc,Key,Value) :-
   if_(find_first_in_t(key_pair_t(Key),_-Value,Assoc),
       true,
       Key=Value).
```

So, does the OP's use-case still work?

```
?- maplist(assoc_key_mapped([x-z,z-x,d-c]), [x,d,e,z,a,z,p], Rs).
Rs = [z,c,e,x,a,x,p].                            % OK. same result as before
```

---

**Building on `find_first_in_t/4`**

```
memberd_t(X,Xs,Truth) :-                        % memberd_t/3
   find_first_in_t(=(X),_,Xs,Truth).

:- meta_predicate exists_in_t(2,?,?).           % exists_in_t/3
exists_in_t(P_2,Xs,Truth) :-
   find_first_in_t(P_2,_,Xs,Truth).
```

Comment: `find_`... imperative. Also, unnecessarily weak due to `E=X`.

Comment: @false. Thx! Instead of using `E=X,Truth=true` I could use `=(E,X,Truth)`. While this would work with above def of `memberd_t/3`, it would not with `exists_in_t/3`. Do you have an idea? (Will edit ASAP anyway.)

Comment: @false. What do you mean by "weak due to E=X"? Is `(=)/3` better? `exists_in_t/3` uses `_` as `X`, which is bad with `(=)/3`... Help!

Comment: Say, `X` cannot influence termination of `P_2`.