# Declarative uses of memberchk/2

Tags: prolog, logical-purity

`memberchk/2` is a commonly defined predicate that is defined in terms of `member/2` like so:

```
memberchk(X, Xs) :-
   once(member(X, Xs)).
```

It therefore succeeds only for the first answer of `member/2`. Its full procedural meaning does not fit into a pure relation. As an example for its non-relational behavior consider

```
?- memberchk(b, [X,b]), X = a.
false.

?- X = a, memberchk(b, [X,b]).
X = a.
```

On the other hand, in many cases `memberchk/2` will be called with *sufficiently instantiated* arguments, where it can be seen as an efficient approximation of a pure relation.

One such pure relation behind is `memberd/2` (using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600)):

```
memberd(E, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(E = X, true, memberd(E, Xs) ).
```

Are there any other pure relations that can be approximated by `memberchk/2` for sufficiently instantiated cases?

In other words: Is `memberd/2` a full, declarative replacement for `memberchk/2` or are there still legitimate cases where `memberchk/2` cannot be replaced by `memberd/2`?

Comment: What do you mean when you speak of *pure relations that can be* **approximated** *by `memberchk/2`"*? Is some  `memberchk/2` goal used as a replacement or as supplement in these cases?

Comment: @repeat: See `bridge.pl` in SICStus: It uses `memberchk/2` where the original version used `member/2`.

Comment: @repeat: it is an approximation, because it works in certain cases like the pure relation. But not in others. Of course, it is not a **safe** approximation.

Comment: Ok, `memberchk/2` approximates `som_rel/2` if the concrete data used has some specific properties? Something like "if memberchk(X,Es) fails then memberd(X,Es) also fails"??

Answer (score 5):

Here is a well-known example use of `member/2` that cannot be represented by `memberd/2`: [`bridge.pl`](http://sourceforge.net/p/gprolog/code/ci/0bafe4bc81e9fbea2d6ef4cdcda209a29c5caf0e/tree/examples/ExamplesFD/bridge.pl) the bridge scheduling problem given by Pascal Van Hentenryck.

In the setup phase `member/2` is used:

```
setup(K,Ende,Disj):-
    jobs(L),
    make_vars(L,K),
    member([stop,_,Ende],K),
    ....
```

So here, effectively the first element in the three-element list is used to select a particular task whereas `memberd/2` uses the entire element for comparison.  As a consequence this `setup/3` leaves open a lot of choicepoints (actually, 219).  Some (like SICStus) use `memberchk/2` in that situation, thereby risking non-monotonicity.

Using the following pure replacement, all choicepoints are avoided.

```
member3l([N,D,A], Plan) :-
   tmember(l3_t(N,D,A),  Plan).

l3_t(N,D,A, X, T) :-
   X = [Ni|_],
   if_(N = Ni, ( X=[N,D,A], T = true ), T = false ).

tmember(P_2, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_( call(P_2, X), true, tmember(P_2, Xs) ).
```

Alternatively using `library(lambda)`:

```
member3li([N,Nd,Na], Plan) :-
   tmember([N,Nd,Na]+\X^T^
       (  X=[Nk|_],
          if_( Nk = N, ( X=[N,Nd,Na], T = true ), T = false ) ),
      Plan).
```

Other uses of `tmember/2`:

```
old_member(X, Xs) :-
   tmember( X+\E^T^( X = E, T = true ; T = false ), Xs).

old_memberd(X, Xs) :-
   tmember(=(X), Xs).
```

Here is a more compact representation:

```
member3l([N,D,A], Plan) :-
   tmember({N,D,A}+\[Ni,Di,Ai]^cond_t(N = Ni, [D,A] = [Di,Ai] ), Plan).
```

Using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/lambda.pl)and `cond_t/3`:

```
cond_t(If_1, Then_0, T) :-
   if_(If_1, ( Then_0, T = true ), T = false ).
```

Comment: s(X). Crafty! The way I see it is that you effectively circumvent the problem I have with `find_first_in_t/4` by pushing "output unifications" into `P_2`. So how about: `memberd(E,Xs) :- tmember(=(E),Xs).` Is that right?

Comment: What does the _t suffix mean? A predicate turned into a boolean function? I guess the idea is doomed to fail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639686/prolog-substitution/33466430#33466430

Answer (score 3):

The following answer does not directly relate to the original question regarding `memberchk/2`; instead, it is a follow-up to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33456560/4609915) which defined [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tmember/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33456560/4609915).

We propose generalizing the idiom `tmember/2` like so:

```
t_non_empty_suffix(P_3, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(call(P_3,Xs,X), true, t_non_empty_suffix(P_3,Xs)).
```

Building on `t_non_empty_suffix/2` and [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord.html), we can define `tmemberX/2` like so:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

tmemberX(P_2, Xs) :-
   t_non_empty_suffix(P_2+\_^call(P_2), Xs).
```

The following `old_memberX/2` and `old_memberdX/2` use `tmemberX/2` instead of `tmember/2`:

```
old_memberX(X, Xs) :-
   tmemberX(X+\E^T^( X = E, T = true ; T = false ), Xs).

old_memberdX(X, Xs) :-
   tmemberX(=(X), Xs).
```

Let's compare `old_member/2` to `old_memberX/2` ...

```
?- old_member(X, [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]).
X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 5 ; false.

?- old_memberX(X, [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]).
X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 5 ; false.
```

... and `old_memberd/2` to `old_memberdX/2`!

```
?- old_memberd(X, [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]).
X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 5 ; false.

?- old_memberdX(X, [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]).
X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 5 ; false.
```

**OK!** How about defining `old_member` / `old_memberd` directly based on `t_non_empty_suffix/2`?

```
old_memberSFX(X, Xs) :-
   t_non_empty_suffix(X+\_^E^T^( X = E, T = true ; T = false ), Xs).

old_memberdSFX(X, Xs) :-
   t_non_empty_suffix(X+\_^E^( X = E ), Xs).
```

Running above queries with these predicates we get:

```
?- old_memberSFX(X, [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]).
X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 5 ; false.

?- old_memberdSFX(X, [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]).
X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ; X = 4 ; X = 5 ; false.
```

**Alright!** Same results as before.

---

Let's dig a bit deeper! As a show-case for `t_non_empty_suffix/2` consider `duplicate_in/2`.

 Using `t_non_empty_suffix/2`, [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord.html), [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708684/4609915), and [`memberd_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29614767/4609915) we define:

```
','(P_1, Q_1, T) :-
   if_(P_1, call(Q_1,T), T = false).

duplicate_in(X, Xs) :-
   t_non_empty_suffix(X+\Es^E^( X = E, memberd_t(E, Es) ), Xs).
```

Sample query:

```
?- duplicate_in(X, [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]).
  X = 2         % [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]    (2 occurs  twice)
; X = 3         % [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]    (3 occurs thrice)
; X = 4         % [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]    (4 occurs  twice)
; false.
```

Comment: This makes reasoning more opaque. `tmember/2` is about members (that is, about the elements **only**). `tsuffix/2` depends on the entire list.

Comment: Also, why insist that `[a]` is not a suffix of `[a]`?

Comment: @false. For `?- tsuffix(Suffix+\Es^(Suffix=Es), [a,b,c]).` I get the following answers: `Suffix = [a,b,c] ;
Suffix = [b,c] ;
Suffix = [c] ;
false.`

Comment: @false. Regarding reasoning, now *that* I get. But isn't `tmemberX/2` all about members, too?

Comment: Correction: `tsuffix/2` only succeeds for a list with at least one element. Why that restriction at all?

Comment: @false. Thx! I see. So `[a,b]` should have suffixes `[a,b]`, `[b]`, and `[]`; `[a,b|non_list]` OTOH only `[a,b|non_list]` and `[b|non_list]`. Right?

Comment: @false. I tried adding the `Suffix=[]` case: it certainly is doable, but I feel like it breaks the idiom. Wouldn't renaming the predicate from `tsuffix/2` to `t_non_empty_suffix/2` (or something better) circumvent the problem?

Answer (score 2):

memberb/2 is a typical example from constructive negation. You can turn the requirement upside down, and for example require:

```
?- ~ member(X, [a,b,c]).
dif(X, a),
dif(X, b),
dif(X, c)
```

Where ~ would be constructive negation. For a discussion on how constructive negation relates to if_ see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33464423/502187).

The disadvantage of fully declarative inductive definitions, for memberd/2 or somesuch is that the Prolog disjunction (;)/2 is not able to simplify
constraints, and that Prolog doesn't have a forall that would also simplify constraints such as diff/2.

So that in the end when you do it correctly with the limited (;)/2 and missig forall you get in the best case complete solutions that contain a lot of redundant constraints when you look at the full solution sets that the interpreter would produce.

Here is an example in Jekejeke Prolog, it requires the Minlog extension for the predicate dif/2 to be available:

```
:- use_module(library(term/herbrand)).
:- use_module(library(basic/lists)).
test(Y) :- dif(X, a), member(Y, [a,X]).

?- test(X).
X = a,
dif(_A, a) ;
dif(X, a)
```

The above two answers basically say `X = a` or `~(X = a)` which is in most logics the same as a single answer `true`.

You would need a Prolog interpreter, that at some points works set oriented. And maybe some operators that would force a set oriented processing. But it might break traditional Prolog code. You can probably not just sneak in fully declarative definitions into code that was based on not so declarative definitions.

Bye

Comment: There is a fine line between reification with `(=)/3` and `if_/3` and constructive negation: `~ member(a, non_list)` would **have** to succeed, whereas here we can take the liberty to fail.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863784/different-2-does-a-pure-determinate-definition-exist#comment49779002_30863784) for a similar example.

Comment: `memberd(1,[X,1])`  (from [this](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/indexingdif.pdf)) is a minimal example for this kind of redundancy.

Comment: @false. Regarding your comment "currently pondering ...": Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31589817/4609915 . Isn't this it?