# How to find the cardinality of a set in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I 'm trying to find the cardinality of a set in Prolog. As is known, a set can haven't elements repeated. I tried this.

```
cardinal([], 0).
cardinal([_|Tail], N):-
    removeRepeated(Tail, ListWithoutRepeated),
    cardinal(ListWithoutRepeated, N1),
    N is N1 + 1.

----------------------------------------------------
consult:                                            

?- cardinal([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5], N).
   N = 6
```

But the correct answer is N = 5. Obviously I'm counting only the items in the tail and ignored if the head is repeated in the tail. 
So I tried something like this. That is to add the head to tail and repeat the above process.

```
join([], L, [L]).
join([Head|Tail], L, [Head|Tail2]):-
   join(Tail,L, Tail2).

cardinal([], 0).
cardinal([Head|Tail], N):-
    join(Tail,Head, List),
    removeRepeated(List, ListWithoutRepeated),
    cardinal(ListWithoutRepeated, N1),
    N is N1 + 1.
```

But when you query an **infinite loop** is generated.
Can someone help me solve this o
can anyone help me out how can I write prolog statement for this?

**Edit**
attached `removeRepeated`

```
removeRepeated([],[]).
removeRepeated([Head|Tail],ListWithoutRepeated):-
    member(Head,Tail),
    !,
    removeRepeated(Tail,ListWithoutRepeated).
removeRepeated([Head|Tail],[Head|ListWithoutRepeated]):-
    removeRepeated(Tail,ListWithoutRepeated).

----------------------------------------------------
consult:                                            

?- removeRepeated([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,8], N).
   N = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `removeRepeated`?

Comment: What do you mean by "can haven't"? Maybe "Cannot have"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teh codez:

```
set_cardinality(Xs, N) :-
   list_nub(Xs, Ys),
   length(Ys, N).
```

using [`list_nub/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36320826/772868). It is possible to improve termination of this definition, since it only terminates if the length of `Xs` is fixed. But before we go into this, let's look at your definitions.

#### Relational names

Try to use names that actually reflect what the relations you define are about. Both `cardinal/2` and `removeRepeated/2` will leave one with the impression that the former is a relation between cardinals, and the latter does something. But relations don't do anything. OK, they "are". Or, they "relate". But these are not really action-filled verbs.

Now for your first definition `cardinal/2`. Actually, I tried **not** to read it. Particularly, because it contains the number one reason for programmer's vertigo — which is

> Recursion

Yes, this makes me very dizzy too. Luckly, your question is about Prolog, and in Prolog we can often hide a lot of things and still get lots of insight. Here is what I looked at first (the things I **did not** look at are <s>striked through</s>).

```
cardinal([], 0).
cardinal([_|Tail], N):-
    removeRepeated(Tail, ListWithoutRepeated),
    cardinal(ListWithoutRepeated, N1),
    N is N1 + 1.
```

The fact, I can handle. Ok, the empty list corresponds to zero. Sounds fine to me. But then, there is the head of this rule: It reads:

> `N` is **independent** of the first element of the list.

That is: For `cardinal([1,2],N)` and `cardinal([2,2],N)` you will get the very same `N` values. How can this be correct?

`removeRepeated/2` (`list_nub/2` might be a more relational name) works nicely for queries that have a ground first argument:

```
?- removeRepeated([1,2], X).
   X = [1,2].
?- removeRepeated([1,2],[1,2]).
   true.
```

However, it unexpectedly fails for:

```
?- removeRepeated([X,2],[1,2]).
   false.    % not relational
?- X = 1, removeRepeated([X,2],[1,2]).
   X = 1.
```

So while the specialization succeeds, the query that is more general fails. This is a clear indication that `removeRepeated/2` is not a pure relation.  For an implementation that works as expected, see [`list_nub/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36320826/772868).

Answer (score 2):

First of all: there is a library `lists` that ships with SWI-Prolog (and some other versions) containing the  [`list_to_set/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=list_to_set%2f2) that you can use to construct a *Set*: a sorted list where every item occurs only once. For example:

```
?- list_to_set([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5],S),length(S,N).
S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
N = 5.
```

Now to comment on your (first) solution. The problem is that you call `removeRepeated/2` unknowing what item is currently in the head of the list in `cardinal/2`. A small fix would be to rewrite the `removeRepeated/2` predicate to `removeRepeated/3`:

```
removeRepeated([],_,[]).
removeRepeated([H|T],H,U) :-
    !,
    removeRepeated(T,H,U).
removeRepeated([X|T],H,[X|U]) :-
    removeRepeated(T,H,U).
```

And call it with:

```
cardinal([], 0).
cardinal([H|Tail],N):-
    removeRepeated(Tail,H,ListWithoutRepeated),
    cardinal(ListWithoutRepeated, N1),
    N is N1 + 1.
```

Mind however it is still inefficient because:

1. the predicate has *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time complexity; and
2. you do not use an accumulator such that the compiler can use *tail recursion*.

Comment: Thank you very much , I'll take my time to see if I can improve the process. Thanks for the help

Comment: The predicate `list_to_set/2` is not a built-in predicate but a library predicate available in a specific Prolog system. Answers to generic Prolog questions that only work in a specific Prolog system should preferably state that explicitly and clearly to avoid trouble for readers using other Prolog systems.

Comment: @PauloMoura: I've updated the answer now mentioning SWI-Prolog. Nevertheless I think it is still a valuable part of the answer (instead of reinventing the wheel every time, look to some library).

Comment: Agreed. Use of libraries, when available, should be encouraged although there's of course pedagogical value of users writing their own solutions.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using only standard predicates is to sort the list and then compute its length:

```
| ?- sort([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5], Set), length(Set, Cardinality).

Cardinality = 5
Set = [1,2,3,4,5]

yes
```

Assuming a decent implementation fo the `sort/2`standard predicate, the time complexity of this solution should be (worst case) O(N*log(N)) + O(N).