# replacing list elements in sicstus prolog

Tags: list, replace, prolog, prolog-dif

I am writing a Prolog predicate that takes arguments (A1, A2, L1, L2) and succeeds if all occurences of A1 within L1 have been changed to A2 in L2.

i.e.:

```
| ?- replace(a, b, [a], X).
X = [b]
```

Here's what I've written:

```
replace(Orig,_,[Other],[Other]) :- Other \== Orig.
replace(Orig,Repl,[Orig],[Repl]).
replace(Orig,Repl,[Other|T1],[Other|T2]) :- Other \== Orig, replace(Orig,Repl,T1,T2).
replace(Orig,Repl,[Orig|T1],[Repl|T2]) :- replace(Orig,Repl,T1,T2).
```

Now, this works, but seems a bit unelegant. Can there be a more elegant solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
replace(A, B, X, Y) :- ( X == A -> Y = B ; Y = X ).
```

Example:

```
?- maplist(replace(1,x), [1,2,3], Ls).
Ls = [x, 2, 3].
```

It is easy to unfold the `maplist/3` call into a recursive predicate if you prefer that.

Comment: maplist isn't in Sicstus, unfortunately.       
edit: hm, apparently Sicstus should have it, but somehow the Sicstus on my machine doesn't. bummer. :)

Comment: Recent versions definitely have it. It's also easy to get a direct recursive definition, you only need to add two lines of code to the replace/4 predicate above and change `X` and `Y` to talk about lists instead of individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

SICStus Prolog features `dif/2` so you can define the relation in a pure manner like so:

```
replacement(A, B, X, Y) :-
   ( A = X, B = Y
   ; dif(A,X), X = Y
   ).

maplist_replacement([], [], _, _).
maplist_replacement([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], A, B) :-
   replacement(A, B, X, Y),
   maplist_replacement(Xs, Ys, A, B).
```

```
?- maplist_replacement([1,2,3],Ys, 1,x).
   Ys = [x,2,3].
?- maplist_replacement([X,Y],[X,Y],A,B).
   B = A, X = A, Y = A
;  B = A, X = A, dif(A,Y)
;  B = A, Y = A, dif(A,X)
;  dif(A,X), dif(A,Y).
```

The last query corresponds to the question: What must `A` and `B` look like such that a two element list will remain the same? There are four answers:

1. `A`, `B`, `X`, and `Y` are all the same.
2. `A`, `B`, and `X` are the same, and `Y` is different.
3. `A`, `B`, and `Y` are the same, and `X` is different.
4. `X` and `Y` are both different to `A`.

In newer versions of SICStus, `maplist/3` is in a library, however the definition is not entirely monotonic.
For a definition of `maplist/3` see [Prolog map procedure that applies predicate to list elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682987/prolog-map-procedure-that-applies-predicate-to-list-elements/6683502#6683502).