# Prolog insert element after first occurrence

Tags: list, prolog

How I can add an element `E` right after the first occurrence of `X` in list `Xs`?

Example:

```
?- insert_right_behind(5,10,[2,4,10,12],Xs).
Xs = [2,4,10,5,12].                     % expected answer
```

At this moment, I have problems understanding
the recursion that needs to be made since I am new to the language.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if `10` doesn't exist, what would you like it to do?

Comment: mbratch, `false` probably

Comment: Yes, false would be the correct result then i guess.

Comment: mbrathc, "first" occurrence.

Comment: Insertion takes place one time, only after the first element is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three predicate clauses:

```
% Inserting after in an empty list is an empty list:
insert_after( _X, _Y, [], [] ).

% If the "after" item is at the head of the list, then the "insert" item can go after it:
insert_after( X, Y, [Y|T], [Y,X|T] ).

% If the head of the list isn't the "after" item, then the result will be
% this with a new tail list that has the "insert" item inserted:
insert_after( X, Y, [H|T], [H|L] ) :-
    Y \= H,
    insert_after( X, Y, T, L ).
```

If the "after" item doesn't exist in the given list, then `insert_after/4` will yield the original list. By removing the first `insert_after` clause above, it will just fail for that case.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works as intended and it's also nice that you have provided some comments to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32403894/4609915) most successful queries left behind useless choicepoints.

We can avoid these choicepoints by using [`if_/3` and `(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) like so:

```
item_following_in_inserted(I,J,[X|Xs],Ys0) :-
   if_(J = X,
       Ys0 = [J,I|Xs],
       (Ys0 = [X|Ys], item_following_in_inserted(I,J,Xs,Ys))).
```

Let's run some queries!

```
?- item_following_in_inserted(5,10,[2,4,12],Xs).
false.                                               % OK, unchanged

?- item_following_in_inserted(5,10,[2,4,10,12],Xs).
Xs = [2,4,10,5,12].                                  % succeeds deterministically

?- item_following_in_inserted(5,10,[2,4,10,12,10],Xs).
Xs = [2,4,10,5,12,10].                               % succeeds deterministically

?- item_following_in_inserted(I,E,Xs,Ys).
  Xs = [      E|_Z], Ys = [      E,I|_Z]             % OK, unchanged
; Xs = [   _A,E|_Z], Ys = [   _A,E,I|_Z], dif(E,_A)
; Xs = [_A,_B,E|_Z], Ys = [_A,_B,E,I|_Z], dif(E,_A), dif(E,_B)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep it simple and use [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append), [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) and [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) like so:

```
item_following_in_inserted(I,J,Xs,Ys) :-
   append(Prefix,[J  |Suffix],Xs),
   maplist(dif(J),Prefix),
   append(Prefix,[J,I|Suffix],Ys).
```

Done! It's query time... First, let's run the query the OP gave:

```
?- item_following_in_inserted(5,10,[2,4,10,12],Xs).
  Xs = [2,4,10,5,12]               % succeeds, but leaves behind choicepoint
; false.
```

What if the item is not a member of the given list?

```
?- item_following_in_inserted(5,10,[2,4,   12],Xs).
false.                             % fails, as expected: 10 is absent
```

Let's check that we *only insert after the first* occurrence—and nowhere else!

```
?- item_following_in_inserted(5,10,[2,4,10,12,10],Xs).
  Xs = [2,4,10,5,12,10]            % single solution
; false.                           % terminates universally
```

What about the most general query of `item_following_in_inserted/4`?

```
?- item_following_in_inserted(I,E,Xs,Ys).
  Xs = [         E|_Z], Ys = [         E,I|_Z]
; Xs = [      _A,E|_Z], Ys = [      _A,E,I|_Z], dif(E,_A)
; Xs = [   _A,_B,E|_Z], Ys = [   _A,_B,E,I|_Z], dif(E,_A), dif(E,_B)
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,E|_Z], Ys = [_A,_B,_C,E,I|_Z], dif(E,_A), dif(E,_B), dif(E,_C)
...
```