# Adding an element to a sublist

Tags: list, prolog

I need to define a predicate `toAdd/3` such that if `Xss` and `Yss` are lists of lists then `toAdd(X,Xss,Yss)` holds if `Yss` can be obtained by adding the element `X` to the end of every element in `Xss`, e.g.

```
?- toAdd(g, [[e],[b,c,f],[k,h]], Yss).
Yss = [[e,g],[b,c,f,g],[k,h,g]].         % expected result
```

I know how to add an element to a list but lists of lists confuse me.

I wrote this code that adds to the end of one list, but not sublists.

```
add(X,[],[X]).
add(X,[A|L],[A|L1]) :-
   add(X,L,L1).
```

Comment: Are you still wondering where `A` comes from in your `add(X,[A|L],[A|L1])` from your comment in your first post of this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702864/adding-an-element-to-a-list-within-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the problem in two parts:

```
- transform each element
  - append to tail
```

then

```
add(_,[],[]). % done
add(X,[E|Es],[T|Ts]) :-
  append(E,[X],T),
  add(X,Es,Ts).
```

we can do inline using findall/3 and member/2

```
1 ?- [user].
|: tooAdd(X, Es, Ts) :- findall(T, (member(E,Es),append(E,[X],T)), Ts).
% user://1 compiled 71.19 sec, 2 clauses
true.

2 ?- tooAdd(g, [[e], [b, c, f], [k, h]], Yss).
Yss = [[e, g], [b, c, f, g], [k, h, g]].
```

Comment: Hello, this worked PERFECTLY then I did something now it doesnt :(

Answer (score 2):

Let's put the predicate `add/3` to use with [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915)!

```
toAdd(X,Xss,Yss) :-
   maplist(add(X),Xss,Yss).
```

Sample query:

```
?- toAdd(g, [[e],[b,c,f],[k,h]], Yss).
  Yss = [[e,g],[b,c,f,g],[k,h,g]]
; false.
```