# SWI-Prolog How to prove if 3 lists have the same sum?

Tags: prolog

I have just started with Prolog and now I have my first problem, which I just can't solve:

I want to give the program 3 lists and as result I want to know if their sum is equal.

So something like this:

```
?- sum_equal([1,2,3],[4,1,1],[5,1,0]).
true
```

Until now I've got this:

```
partsum([],0).
partsum([Head|Tail],Solution) :- 
    partsum(Tail, Solution2), 
    Solution is Head+Solution2.

sum_equal([Head|Tail],[Head2|Tail2],[Head3|Tail3]):-
    sum1=partsum([Head|Tail],sum1),
    sum2=partsum([Head2|Tail2],sum2),
    sum3=partsum([Head3|Tail3],sum3),
    sum1=:=sum2,
    sum1=:=sum3.
```

But now I get the following message:

evaluable 'sum1' does not exist.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of things I've noticed.

Prolog variables must start with a capital letter, so sum1 needs to be Sum1 etc.

In the lines like

```
sum1=partsum([Head|Tail],sum1),
```

the sum1= should not be there because partsum is returns with a value in sum1. so the lines should be similar to

```
partsum([Head|Tail],Sum1),
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. I thought you use only capital letters if you   pass variables and here I give the name. But I think now I got it.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, we assume that *all numbers used are integers*, which allows us to use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd).
```

To define `sum_equal/3` we proceed step by step—it's as easy as one, two, three!

1. Based on ...

   - [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915), part of the [Prolog prologue](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue),
   - the widely available predicate [`length/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915),
   - and the [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) library predicate [`sum/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html)

   ... we define the following two auxiliary predicates:

   ```
   sum_of_zs(S,Zs) :-
      length(Zs,_),                % ensure sufficient instantiation for sum/3
      sum(Zs,#=,S).

   all_zs_have_the_same_sum(Zss,S) :-
      maplist(sum_of_zs(S),Zss).
   ```
2. `sum_equal/3` is a mere specialization of `all_zs_have_the_same_sum/2`:

   ```
   sum_equal(Xs,Ys,Zs) :-
      all_zs_have_the_same_sum([Xs,Ys,Zs],_).
   ```
3. We're done with coding. Let's put it to good use and run the sample query given by the OP:

   ```
   ?- sum_equal([1,2,3],[4,1,1],[5,1,0]).
   true.
   ```