# Prolog: Determine if the intersection of two lists is empty

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to figure out how to determine if the intersection of two lists is empty in Prolog. From what I understand, this is they have no elements in common. I'm new to Prolog(as of last night). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my attempt:

```
% returns true if head is not a member of List?
intersection([],_).
intersection([Head|Tail],List) :- 
   \+ member(Head,List),  
   intersection(Tail,List).
```

Second Attempt:

```
?- intersect([A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H]).

intersect(L1,L2) :-
    intersection(L1,L2,[]).
```

mbratch's resolution solved the problem.

Solution:

```
?-intersect([a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h]).

intersect(L1,L2):-
    intersection(L1,L2,[]).
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting false, not sure what Im missing. I updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: You're using variables instead of atoms. Try `intersect([a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h]).` If you use variables, Prolog will say they can intersect because it will be able to unify `A` with `E` for example, being that they're variables. Variables begin with a capital letter. Atoms ("constants") begin with lower case.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @ mbratch `intersection/3` is NOT a SWI-Prolog built-in predicate. It's a library predicate defined in the `lists` module. In SWI-Prolog, modules are auto-loaded by default when one of their exported predicates is called. Awareness of the SWI-Prolog auto-loading would go along way in avoiding mistaken library predicates for built-in predicates, an unfortunate common occurrence here on SO.

Comment: @PauloMoura apologies. I stand corrected. Since I didn't need to include any special libraries, I thought it was built-in.

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient solution (in general) compared with computing the intersection of the two lists is to fail as soon as a common element is found:

```
empty_intersection(List1, List2) :-
    \+ (member(Element, List1), member(Element, List2)).
```

Answer (score 3):

**Stay pure!** It's as easy as 1,2,3:

1. Using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) and [`dif/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002ddif.html) ([prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)), we define `list_nonmember/2`:

```
    list_nonmember(Xs,E) :-
       maplist(dif(E),Xs).
```

2. Using [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) and `list_nonmember/2`, we define `none_intersect/2`:

```
    none_intersect(Xs,Ys) :-
       maplist(list_nonmember(Ys),Xs).
```

3. Ready to go! Let's run some queries!

```
    ?- none_intersect([a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h]).
    true.

    ?- none_intersect([a,b,c,d],[e,f,a,g,h]).
    false.

    ?- none_intersect([a,b,g,c,d],[e,f,g,h]).
    false.
```