# Prolog - Increase all the numbers of a list by 1

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I tried this

```
 fun([],[]).
 fun([A|_],B) :- number(A), B is A +1,!.
 fun([H|T],R) :- fun(T,R).
```

I know it's wrong, could you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not consistent and you're not finishing the recursion.

With your code, something like this is true:

```
fun([a,b,c],X) .
```

and will result in X having the value `[]`, but

```
fun([a,1,b],X) .
```

will result in X having the value `2`.

If you want to find the first number in the list and increment it by one, something like this will do:

```
fun([X|Xs],Y) :- number(X) , ! , Y is X+1 .
fun([_|Xs],Y) :- fun(Xs,Y) .
```

If you want to increment each number in the list, then try something like this:

```
fun( []    , []      ) .  % if the source list is exhausted, we're done.
fun( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % otherwise,
  number(X) ,             % - if X is a number,
  Y is A+1                % - we increment it to get Y
  fun( Xs , Ys ) .        % - and recurse down on the tails of the respective lists
fun( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- % otherwise, add X to the result list
  \+ number(X) ,          % - assuming X is not a number,
  fun(Xs,Ys) .            % - and recurse down.
```

You should not that this could be more concisely states as

```
fun( [] , [] ) :-
fun( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :-
  increment(X,Y) ,
  fun( Xs , Ys )
  .

increment(X,Y) :- number(X) , ! , Y is X+1 .
increment(X,X) .
```

Or, more concisely yet

```
fun( [] , [] ) .
fun( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :-
  ( number(X) -> Y is X+1 ; Y = X ) ,
  fun(Xs,Ys).
```

The `A -> B ; C` construct is the [implication operator](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=send_arrow/2).

Answer (score 3):

For seeing that your program cannot work, you can either try it out:

```
?- fun([1],L).
   L = 2.
?- fun([1],[]).
   true.
?- fun([X],L).
   L = [].
```

So this shows clearly non-relational behavior: In the first query we ask for an `L` and get `L = 2` as an answer, but then we ask about `[]` being an answer ; and the system accepts that too. Clearly, your definition cannot be a relation. The culprit is certainly the cut.

Apart from that, there are also other ways to see problems. It suffices to look at one rule alone. The first rules (`fun([A|_],B) :- number(A), B is A +1,!.`) says that the second argument must be an integer (in certain situations). But it should be a list. The second rule (`fun([H|T],R) :- fun(T,R).`) says that any element can be skipped. Clearly that cannot be part of a meaningful definition.

The most concise way would use  the higher-order predicate [`maplist/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist) and lambda expressions as defined in [library(lambda)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl). Written this way, an intermediary predicate is usually not used.

```
fun(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(\X^Y^(Y is X+1), Xs, Ys).
```

The next version avoids lambdas and uses a concrete definition instead:

```
msucc(X, Y) :-
   Y is X+1.

fun(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(msucc, Xs, Ys).
```

In fact, there is a predefined predicate `succ/2` which is present in many Prologs and is [part of the Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#succ).

```
fun(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(msucc, Xs, Ys).
```

The most "pedestrian" way of defining it would be directly with a predicate definition:

```
fun([], []).
fun([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
   Y is X+1,
   fun(Xs, Ys).
```

Which one do you prefer?

For more about the maplist-family: [Prolog map procedure that applies predicate to list elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682987/prolog-map-procedure-that-applies-predicate-to-list-elements/6683502#6683502)

---

If you want to learn Prolog, stick to to pure relations first. Avoid the cut. Avoid side effects like `write`. Avoid even `(is)/2`. Use [successor-arithmetics](/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics) and later [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd). Study termination and non-termination [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice), and [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg).