# sort a list of structures by the size of a list

Tags: prolog

I need to sort a list of structures in this format: `(A, B, [...])` by the length of the list.

For example, if I have:

```
[(A,B,[1,2,3,4]),(A,B,[1,2]),(A,B,[1,2,3,4,5]),(A,B,[1,2,3])]
```

After the sorting I want this:

```
[(A,B,[1,2]),(A,B,[1,2,3]),(A,B,[1,2,3,4]),(A,B,[1,2,3,4,5])]
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map each element `El` to a structure `N-El` and use the built-in `keysort/2`.

```
el_keyed(El,N-El) :-
   El = (_,_,L),
   length(L, N).

list_lulasorted(Els, ElsS) :-
   maplist(el_keyed, Els, KVs),
   keysort(KVs, KVsS),
   maplist(el_keyed, ElsS, KVsS).
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868) should your Prolog system not provide `maplist/3`.

The last step might be "accelerated" by:

```
keyvalue_value(_-V, V).

..., maplist(keyvalue_value, KVsS, ElsS), ...
```

Alternatively, using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) no auxiliary definition is needed:

```
list_lulasorted(Els, ElsS) :-
   maplist(\El^(N-El)^( El=(_,_,L), length(L, N) ), Els, KVs),
   keysort(KVs, KVsS),
   maplist(\(_-V)^V^true, KVsS, ElsS).
```

Some notes: `(A, B, L)` is not as frequent as it is in Haskell or ML. Instead, either use a structure like `.(A, B, L)` or maybe `(A*B)-L` depending on what `A` and `B` actually mean.