# Prolog Operator Expected Error

Tags: prolog, syntax-error, meta-predicate

I have searched Prolog Operator expected error questions at stack overflow, however I can't identify the error I am getting :

```
4:26: Syntax error: Operator expected
% 3.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 3 clauses
```

The code is simple:

```
inc(N,R) :-
  R is N + 1. % Simple code to increment a number.

mapcar( F , []    , []     ).  % Base case 
mapcar( F , [H|T] ,[RH|RT] ) :- % Increment head and put it in Result Head and Recurse for Tail
  F(H,RH),
  mapcar(F,T,RT).
```

Comment: `F(H,RH)` is invalid. What do you intend with that expression?

Comment: instead of F(H,RH) use call(F,H,RH) or Pred =.. [F,H,RH], call(Pred)

Comment: @lurker so should i put f instead of F.

Comment: @CapelliC I changed F to f and my program compiled without error, but it is not working correctly. It is expected to increment all elelents in the list.

Comment: @edbale that won't fix it, you should use `call` as CapelliC suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a duplicate of this question: [Prolog map procedure that applies predicate to list elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682987/prolog-map-procedure-that-applies-predicate-to-list-elements)

But I'll bite. You cansimply say, as was suggested:

```
map( _ , []     , []     ) .
map( G , [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :-
  call(G,X,Y)  ,
  map(G,Xs,Ys) .
```