# Checking that a list contains only zeros

Tags: prolog

I have been given a question in my assignment that asks to write a Prolog program that takes as input a list of numbers and succeeds if the list
contains only `0s`.

I am having trouble on how to make the program search for zeroes. For example, a query like:

```
?- zero([0,0,0,0]).
```

Should give us true and it should return false whenever there's a number other than zero in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, one would not define a proper predicate for this, but rather use [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868) for the purpose:

```
..., maplist(=(0), Zs), ...
```

To give a concrete example:

```
?- Zs =[A,B,C], maplist(=(0), Zs).
```

This query corresponds to:

```
?- Zs = [A,B,C], call(=(0), A), call(=(0), B), call(=(0), C).
```

or even simpler:

```
?- Zs = [A,B,C], 0 = A, 0 = B, 0 = C.
```

If you want to define this as a separate predicate, remember to use a good name for it.  Each element of the list is a zero, and the relation describes the entire list of such zeros.  The convention for lists in this case is to use the plural word. Thus `zeros/1`:

```
zeros([]).
zeros([0|Zs]) :-
   zeros(Zs).
```

Answer (score 1):

why are you asking us to do your homework for you?
anyway, it's very simple recursion. something like:

```
zero([]).
zero([0|T]) :- zero(T).
```

just keep peeling of zero's until your list is empty. it isn't so hard ;)