# prolog replace element in a list with another element, using a set function header?

Tags: list, replace, prolog

I have to write the tr rule to translate all occurrences of a list element value to another value.

`tr(A,B,L,M)` if list M is the same as list L, except that every occurrence of A in L is replaced by B. For instance:

```
?- tr(1,2,[1,4,1,5],L).
L = [2, 4, 2, 5].
```

What I have so far:

```
tr(_, _, [], []).
tr(O, R, [O|T], [R|T2]) :- tr(O, R, T, T2).
tr(O, R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- H \= O, tr(O, R, T, T2).
```

Is there a way to replace the `tr(_, _, [], []).` with `tr(A,B,L,M).` so that it uses the letters `A,B,L,M`?

Comment: And why would you want that? The rule `tr(_,_,[],[])` matches the case for empty list, and in such a way is clear to read. What would you gain by having 4 different variables there?

Comment: Ask yourself: "Which element can be replaced by another in an empty list?"

Comment: `tr(_, _, [], []).` is the most suitable way to express that particular rule. You could say, `tr(A, B, L, M) :- L = [], M = [].` but it's slightly less efficient and you'll get a singleton variable warning on `A` and `B`. Or you could say, `tr(_A, _B, L, M) :- L = [], M = [].` to get rid of the warnings but it's still not as clear as `tr(_, _, [], []).`.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern I learned from @false. I am currently learning but maybe you can also use some of it for your problem:

```
    tr(_,_,[],[]).
    tr(X,Y,[X|Xs],[Y|Rs]) :-
      tr(X,Y,Xs,Rs).
    tr(X,Y,[W|Ws],[W|Rs]) :-
      dif(X,W),
      tr(X,Y,Ws,Rs).
```

Ex:

```
    ?- tr(1,2,[1,4,1,5],L).
    L = [2, 4, 2, 5] ;
    false.

    ?- tr(A,B,[1,4,1,5],[2, 4, 2, 5]).
    A = 1,
    B = 2 ;
    false.
```

Comment: Nice, now make it more compact with [`if_/3`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868) and [`maplist/3`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868)! One line with one goal is enough!

Comment: Try out and interpret the question: `?- tr(A,B,[C],[C]).` What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

maplist can do the job :

```
tr(A, B, L, M) :-
    maplist(tr_one(A,B), L, M).

tr_one(A,B,A,B).
tr_one(A,_,B,B) :-
    A \= B.
```

with same answers as @guest's queries.

Comment: Please consider using `dif/2` instead of `(\=)/2`. It helps preserve logical soundness when using non-ground Prolog terms.