# Prolog binding arguments

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

In sicstus prolog, there's a predicate:

```
maplist(:Pred, +List)
```

`Pred` is supposed to take just one argument - `List` element. How can I pass a 2-argument predicate, with first argument defined? In other languages it would be written as:

```
maplist(pred.bind(SomeValue), List)
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868)

Comment: Please note that the definition in SICStus Prolog is not quite correct. As an example `maplist(=(1), L)` only succeeds with one answer `L = []`. Further answers are incorrectly omitted. See above link how you can define this predicate yourself!

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about binding arguments, not rewriting maplist.

Comment: Please reread the line above, I gave you exactly such an example!

Comment: Thanks, I've misunderstood that answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`maplist(P_1, Xs)` will call `call(P_1, X)` for each element of `Xs`. The built-in predicate `call/2` adds one further argument to `P_1` and then calls this with `call/1`.  To indicate that a further argument is needed, it is very helpful to use a name like `P_1` meaning "one extra argument is needed".

So if you have already a predicate of arity 2, say, `(=)/2`, you will pass `=(2)` to maplist:

```
?- maplist(=(2), Xs).
   Xs = []
;  Xs = [2]
;  Xs = [2,2]
;  ... .
```

Since the definition in SICStus' library is unfortunately incorrect, rather use the following definition:

```
:- meta_predicate(maplist(1,?)).
:- meta_predicate(maplist_i(?,1)).

maplist(P_1, Xs) :-
   maplist_i(Xs, P_1).

maplist_i([], _P_1).
maplist_i([E|Es], P_1) :-
   call(P_1, E),
   maplist_i(Es, P_1).
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868) for more.

Just a nice further example about lists of lists.

```
?- Xss = [[A],[B,C]], maplist(maplist(=(E)), Xss).
   Xss = [[E], [E, E]], A = B, B = C, C = E.
```