# Translating a list to another list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I Tried to write a simple code in Prolog which translate a list to another list. for instance, if we call `listtrans([a,b,c],L)`, `L` will become `[1,2,3]`. (a,b,c is replaced with 1,2,3). But i faced with a syntax error in last line. what is the problem? here is my code:

```
trans(a,1).
trans(b,2).
trans(c,3).

listtrans([],L).
listtrans([H|T],L1):-
   trans(H,B),
   append(B,L,L2),
   listtrans(T,L2).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is very likely because in your code:

```
listtrans([H|T],L1):-
   trans(H,B),
   append(B,L,L2),
   listtrans(T,L2).
```

the variable `L1` is declared in the head, but not referenced anywhere: you mispelled something?

Anyway, your code is not going to work.

Moreover, using `append/3` for this kind of tasks which are easily defined by recursion is considered **terrible** (also because of the bad performance you get out of it).

Applying a function to a list is straightforward. You already know that in prolog you don't write `Y = f(X)` but rather declare the *functional relation* between `X` and `Y` as: `f(X, Y).`. (That's basically what you did with `trans(X,Y)`).

Now the (easy) recursive formulation:

- the transformed empty list is the empty list
- the transformation of `[X|Xs]` is `[Y|Ys]` if `trans(X,Y)` and we recursively transform `Xs` into `Ys`

or expressed in prolog:

```
listtrans([],[]).
listtrans([X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :- trans(X,Y), listtrans(Xs,Ys).
```

I recommend you reading the first 4 chapters of [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online) to better understand these concepts.

Answer (score 2):

There are no syntactic errors, only semantic ones. This is it, with corrections:

```
listtrans([],[]).
listtrans([H|T],L1):-
   trans(H,B),
   append([B],L2,L1),
   listtrans(T,L2).
```

But this is not Prolog style. One writes rather:

```
listtrans([],[]).
listtrans([A|As],[I|Is]):-
   trans(A,I),
   listtrans(As,Is).
```

Note that in Prolog explicitly appending elements is much rarer than in languages supporting functions. As an extra bonus, you can now use the relation in both directions:

```
?- listtrans([a,b,c],Is).
   Is = [1,2,3].
?- listtrans(As, [1,2,3]).
   As = [a,b,c].
```

And you can write this more compactly:

```
listtrans(As, Is) :-
   maplist(trans, As, Is).
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868) for more.