# How to translate a list into another in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to make something like a list dictionary in Prolog. I want to transfer a list of numbers from German to English.

Input:
`trnslt([eins,drei,neun],X).`
Output:
`X = [one,three,nine]`
I've thought of an idea to make an if statement but then I thought this won't work.
I would be thankful if anyone provided me with the idea and the code to fully understand the concept.

Edit:
I have read the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818607/translating-a-list-to-another-list-in-prolog) and got the clauses, but actually did not understand anything actually, so can someone tell me how it works?

Comment: Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868).

Comment: Hello again! I understood everything, but only one thing couldn't understand.
```listtrans([X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :- trans(X,Y), listtrans(Xs,Ys).```
How does Prolog understand this rule, or in other meaning how can I understand it?

Answer (score 1):

**1-** Define the `facts`.

**2-** `translate` predicate checks each `German number` in the list `[H|T]`, then searches the facts number, and then stores the `English number` in the `[X|List]`.

**CODE:**

```
%Facts
number(eins, one).
number(zwei, two).
number(drei, three).
number(vier, four).
number(fünf, five).
number(sechs, six).
number(sieben, seven).
number(acht, eight).
number(neun, nine).
number(zehn, ten).

translate([],[]).
translate([H|T],[X|List]):-
    number(H,X),
    translate(T,List).
```

**Examples:**

```
?- translate([eins,drei,neun],X).
X = [one, three, nine]

?- translate([drei],X).
X = [three]

?- translate([drei,zehn,acht,sechs],X).
X = [three, ten, eight, six]
```