# Removing heads from lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate to remove the head from every list in list of lists and add the tails to a new list. The resulting list should be returned as the second parameter.

Here's the attempt:

```
construct_new(S,New) :-
    New = [],
    new_situation(S,New).

new_situation([],_).
new_situation([H|T], New) :-
    chop(H, H1),
    new_situation(T, [H1|New]).

chop([_|T], T).
```

You would call it like this:

```
construct_new([[x,x],[b,c],[d,e,f]],S).
```

This, however, only produces output `true.`.

Comment: Think in terms of relations between lists. Take for example the clause `new_situation([], _).` This cannot be right: Do you really want this to hold for *any* second argument, such as for example `?- new_situation([], prolog).`, which currently succeeds? Since you are describing relations, ideally usable in all directions, avoid imperative names like "chop". Use more declarative names like `list_without_head/2` to describe the two arguments in a meaningful relational way.

Comment: Can't help myself thinking that the predicate should be called `queen_of_hearts/2` ...

Comment: @PauloMoura that's brilliant (+1) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Step-by-step execution

1. Your query is `construct_new(Input,Output)`, for some instanciated `Input` list.
2. The first statement in `construct_new/2` unifies `Output` (a.k.a. `New`) with the empty list. *Where is the returned list supposed to be available for the caller? Both arguments are now unified.*
3. You call `new_situation(Input,[])`
4. You match the second clause `new_situation([H|T],[])`, which performs its task recursively (step 4, ...), until ...
5. You reach `new_situation([],_)`, which *successfully* discards the intermediate list you built.

#### Solutions

- Write a simple recursive predicate:

  ```
  new_situation([],[]).
  new_situation([[_|L]|T],[L|R]) :-
      new_situation(T,R).
  ```
- Use `maplist`:

  ```
  construct_new(S,R) :-
      maplist(chop,S,R).
  ```

#### Remark

As pointed out by other answers and comments, your predicates are badly named. `construct_new` is not a relation, but an action, and could be used to represent almost anything. I tend to like `chop` because it clearly conveys the act of beheading, but this is not an appropriate name for a relation. *repeat*'s `list_head_tail(L,H,T)` is declarative and associates variables to their roles. When using `maplist`, the other predicate (`new_situation`) doesn't even need to exist...

<sub>...even though [guillotine/3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillotine#Reign_of_Terror) is tempting.</sub>

Comment: In Prolog achieving tail-recursiveness often is easier than in functional programming languages.

Comment: I suggest you kick `new_situation/3` and remove the references of your answer to comments. Then we can "clean up" the comments...

Comment: Albeit tempting, `guillotine/3` doesn't express the relational behavior of the predicate. ;)

Comment: @lurker Unfortunately. Maybe `bodies_heads_corpses`

Comment: Yes, I think that conveys the relation.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with a DCG:

```
owth(Lists, Tails) :-
    phrase(tails(Tails), Lists).

tails([]) --> [].
tails([T|Tails]) --> [[_|T]], tails(Tails).
```

Yielding these queries:

```
| ?- owth([[x,x],[b,c],[d,e,f]], T).

T = [[x],[c],[e,f]] ? ;

no
| ?- owth(L, [[x],[c],[e,f]]).

L = [[_,x],[_,c],[_,e,f]]

yes
```

(`owth` = *Off with their heads!* or, if used the other direction, *On with their heads!*)

If you also want to capture the heads, you can enhance it as follows:

```
owth(Lists, Heads, Tails) :-
    phrase(tails(Heads, Tails), Lists).

tails([], []) --> [].
tails([H|Hs], [T|Tails]) --> [[H|T]], tails(Hs, Tails).
```

Answer (score 2):

We use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/[3-4]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) with one of these following auxiliary predicates:

```
list_tail([_|Xs],Xs).

list_head_tail([X|Xs],X,Xs).
```

Let's run some queries!

```
?- maplist(list_head_tail,[[x,x],[b,c],[d,e,f]],Heads,Tails).
Heads = [x,b,d],
Tails = [[x],[c],[e,f]].
```

If you are *only* interested in the tails, use `maplist/4` together with `list_head_tail/3` ...

```
?- maplist(list_head_tail,[[x,x],[b,c],[d,e,f]],_,Tails).
Tails = [[x],[c],[e,f]].
```

... or, even simpler, `maplist/3` in tandem with `list_tail/2`:

```
?- maplist(list_tail,[[x,x],[b,c],[d,e,f]],Tails).
Tails = [[x],[c],[e,f]].
```

Comment: What is wrong with the `chop/2` that OP already defined in their question?

Comment: @Boris. `chop/2` is a **bad** name.

Comment: For contrast: `chop(X, Y)` is true iff ... ??? (nobody knows from the name). `list_head_tail(Ls, H, Ts)` is true iff ... (it's easy to see what is intended from the name alone).

Comment: So is `length/2` instead of `list_length/2`, and `is/2` should really have had the second argument as the output argument, and don't even get me started on `list_member` etc. :D But yes, it is a bad name.

Comment: @Boris. You're right. A lot of names have appeared and stayed during the past 40 years of Prolog history. Be that as it may, the time is always right to lead by example!

Comment: [slurp](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp) and [spit](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/spit)?

Comment: @coredump or [library(filesex)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=filesex)?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the somewhat ugly one-liner with `findall/3`:

```
?- L = [[x,x],[b,c],[d,e,f]],
   findall(T, ( member(M, L), append([_], T, M) ), R).
R = [[x], [c], [e, f]].
```

(OK, technically a two-liner. Either way, you don't even need to define a helper predicate.)

But definitely prefer the `maplist` solution that uses `chop` as shown [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32904093/1812457).

If you do the maplist expansion by hand, and name your `chop/2` a bit better, you would get:

```
lists_tails([], []).
lists_tails([X|Xs], [T|Ts]) :-
    list_tail(X, T),
    lists_tails(Xs, Ts).
```

And since you can do unification in the head of the predicate, you can transform this to:

```
lists_tails([], []).
lists_tails([[_|T]|Xs], [T|Ts]) :-
    lists_tails(Xs, Ts).
```

But this is identical to what you have in the other answer.

Exercise: why can't we say:

```
?- maplist(append([_]), R, [[x,x],[b,c],[d,e,f]]).
```

Comment: The code based on `findall/3` breaks down when used with non-ground terms. The query `?- L = [[A,B],[C,D,E]], findall(T, ( member(M, L), append([_], T, M) ), R).` gives as answer `L = [[A, B], [C, D, E]], R = [[_G220], [_G211, _G214]].`