# DCG version for maplist/3

Tags: prolog, dcg, meta-predicate

The following meta-predicate is often useful.  Note that it cannot be called `maplist//2`, because its expansion would collide with `maplist/4`.

```
maplistDCG(_P_2, []) -->
   [].
maplistDCG(P_2, [A|As]) -->
   {call(P_2, A, B)},
   [B],
   maplistDCG(P_2, As).
```

There are several issues here. Certainly the name.  But also the terminal `[B]`: should it be explicitly disconnected from the connecting goal?

Without above definition, one has to write either one of the following - both having serious termination issues.

```
maplistDCG1(P_2, As) -->
   {maplist(P_2, As, Bs)},
   seq(Bs).

maplistDCG2(P_2, As) -->
   seq(Bs),
   {maplist(P_2, As, Bs)}.

seq([]) -->
   [].
seq([E|Es]) -->
   [E],
   seq(Es).
```

Comment: I don't get fully your question: I can see that [dcgutils](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=dcgutils):[seqmap](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/dcgutils/prolog/dcg_core.pl?show=src) family  take a different approach than yours...

Answer (score 2):

Does `{call(P_2,A,B)}, [B]` have advantages over `[B], {call(P_2,A,B)}`?
<sup>(And, if so, shouldn't [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) get something like that, too?)</sup>

Let's put corresponding [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) and non-[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) variants side-by-side<sup>1</sup>:

1. [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) `[B],{call(P_2,A,B)}` and non-[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) `Bs0 = [B|Bs], call(P_2,A,B)`

   ```
   maplistDCG(_,[]) --> [].        %     maplist(_,[],[]).          
   maplistDCG(P_2,[A|As]) -->      %     maplist(P_2,[A|As],Bs0) :- 
      [B],                         %        Bs0 = [B|Bs],    
      {call(P_2,A,B)},             %        call(P_2,A,B),
      maplistDCG(P_2,As).          %        maplist(P_2,As,Bs).
   ```
2. [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) `{call(P_2,A,B)},[B]` and non-[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) `call(P_2,A,B), Bs0 = [B|Bs]`

   ```
   maplistDCG(_,[]) --> [].        %     maplist(_,[],[]).
   maplistDCG(P_2,[A|As]) -->      %     maplist(P_2,[A|As],Bs0) :-
      {call(P_2,A,B)},             %        call(P_2,A,B),
      [B],                         %        Bs0 = [B|Bs],
      maplistDCG(P_2,As).          %        maplist(P_2,As,Bs).
   ```

Above, we highlighted the goal ordering in use now:

- by `maplist/3`, as defined [in this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) and [in the Prolog prologue](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist)
- by `maplistDCG//2`, as defined in this question by the OP

If we consider that ...

- ... termination properties need to be taken into account and ...
- ... [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) and non-[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) variants should better behave the same<sup>2</sup> ...

... we find that the variable should *not* be explicitly disconnected from the connecting goal. The *natural* DCG analogue of `maplist/3` is `maplistDCG//2` defined as follows:

```
maplistDCG(_,[]) -->
   [].
maplistDCG(P_2,[A|As]) -->
   [B],
   {call(P_2,A,B)},
   maplistDCG(P_2,As).
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** To emphasize commonalities, we adapted variable names, code layout, and made some unifications explicit.</sup>
<sup>**Footnote 2:** ... unless we have really **good** reasons for their divergent behaviour ...</sup>

Comment: And then there is *steadfastness*.

Comment: @false. With `maplist/3` reordering is okay w.r.t.  steadfastness, but with `maplistDCG//2` it's an issue?