# Decomposing a matrix to a list of first element and sub list of remaining elements in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Test Case

```
?- decompose([[1,2,8],[3,4],[5,6]], L1, L2).
L1 = [1,3,5], L2 = [[2,8],[4],[6]] ? ;
no
```

I had tried another implementation however the feedback given was that it was inefficient.

The inefficient implementation

```
listFirst([], []).
listFirst([H1|T1], [H2|Z]):-
    H1 = [H2|_],
    listFirst(T1, Z).

listFollowers([], []).
listFollowers([H1|T1], [T2|Z]):-
    H1 = [H2|T2],
    listFollowers(T1, Z).

decompose(A,L1,L2) :-
    listFollowers(A, L2),
    listFirst(A, L1).
```

Comment: The implementation you're showing is inefficient because it's going through the list twice instead of just once. You can combine  what your `listFirst` does with what your `listFollowers` does just by including an additional argument.

Comment: Arguably, said implementation has some inefficiency... but you need not worry about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on [@findall's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34149015/4609915)... How about using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915)?

```
list_head_tail([X|Xs], X, Xs).

decompose(Mss, Hs, Ts) :-
   maplist(list_head_tail, Mss, Hs, Ts).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- decompose([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]], Heads, Tails).
Heads = [a,d], Tails = [[b,c],[e,f]].

?- decompose([[1,2,8],[3,4],[5,6]], L1, L2).
L1 = [1,3,5], L2 = [[2,8],[4],[6]].
```

Answer (score 2):

As lurker says, the functions of your `listFirst` and `listFollowers` can be combined into a predicate to do those at once. Like this;

```
decompose([[H|T]|T0], [H|L1], [T|L2]) :- decompose(T0, L1, L2).
decompose([], [], []).
```

Comment: What's the use of `!` in the first clause?

Comment: Sorry, I've rearranged that and removed the un-meaningful cut. My poor-functioning interpreter (which I used for testing that) cannot guess there actually is no other choice as entering the 1st case of the predicate.

Comment: OK. The cut would have rendered the most general query `decompose(Mss,Hs,Ts)` quite incomplete! Which interpreter do you use?

Comment: Thank you for the correction. That is what I made just for learning purpose. You can see it in my Github page linked from my profile.