# what is the difference between count /3 and for/3 in prolog?

Tags: sicstus-prolog, eclipse-clp

What is the difference between count/3 and for/3 in prolog ?
and how to use *for-loop* with decrementation **-1** like (***for(I,9,0,-1)***)?

- for example :

  > Dec=-2, Min_bound=0, Max_bound=9
  >   Result =>   9,7,5,3,1

Comment: Neither `count/3` or `for/3` are standard (official or de facto) Prolog predicates. I suggest you tag your question with the Prolog system that you're using. But its documentation should provide the answer you're seeking.

Comment: i use sisctus-prolog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is the difference between count/3 and for/3 in Prolog  (ECLiPSe/SICStus)?

The difference is in the "mode", i.e. whether the ***Max*** argument is used as *input* (+) or *output* (-).

- The template ***for(-I,+Min,+Max)*** is used for *controlling* the number of loop iterations.  The value of *Max* must be known at the time you start the loop, i.e. it can be a number

  ```
  ?- ( for(I,1,3) do writeln(I) ).
  1
  2
  3
  ```

  or it can be an expression with instantiated variables

  ```
  ?- Next=4, ( for(I,1,Next-1) do writeln(I) ).
  1
  2
  3
  ```

  The termination condition is *I >= Max*.
- The template ***count(-I,+From,-To)*** is used to *count* the number of iterations.  At the time you start the loop, *To* would normally be an uninstantiated variable, which, at the end of the loop, is unified with the number of loop iterations.  In such a setting, the number of iterations must be controlled by something else, e.g. the length of a list, as in this example:

  ```
  ?- ( foreach(X,[a,b,c]),count(I,1,N) do writeln(I-X) ).
  1 - a
  2 - b
  3 - c

  N = 3
  Yes (0.01s cpu)
  ```
- Because Prolog of course allows you to use a value instead of an uninstantiated variable, you *can* use the template ***count(-I,+From,+To)***, but you should be aware that the termination condition is *I=To*, not *I>=To*.

The ***do-loop*** construct, to which the *for/3* and *count/3* iterators belong, is an attempt to provide compact notation for the common case of iterative recursion, and to do so in a way reminiscent of procedural loop notation.  The unique properties of logical variables and the generally bi-directional nature of Prolog lead to some interesting features, e.g. using the *foreach/2* iterator you can use the same loop code to either traverse an existing list or to construct a new list.  In the present case of iteration over numbers, this symmetry sadly isn't achieved, hence the two different iterators that you ask about.

#### How to use for-loop with decrementation

Nothing special, really:

```
    ?- ( for(I,9,0,-2) do writeln(I) ).
    9
    7
    5
    3
    1
    Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

or, for collecting the results in a list:

```
    ?- ( for(I,9,0,-2),foreach(I,Is) do true ).
    Is = [9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
    Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

**Edit**: It has been pointed out that the above does not work in SICStus (4.3.2), because the *for/4* iterator is not supported.  You can still do such loops using the general-purpose *fromto/4* iterator, but you have to do some arithmetic yourself, e.g.

```
?- ( fromto(9,I,I1,-1) do I1 is I-2, writeln(I) ).
9
7
5
3
1
Yes (0.01s cpu)
```

For the general case, this gets a bit tricky, so that you may actually get clearer code using a recursive solution...

Comment: Given your interpretation of `count`, an `uninstantiation_error` seems quite helpful in that situation.

Comment: @jschimpf   the last result `( for(I,9,0,-2) do writeln(I) ).` is not with **SICStus-prolog**, it is with **TKEClipse** .

Comment: @jschimpf where i find the library that contains the predicate **for/4** in the C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ECLiPSe 6.1 \ lib?

Comment: You are right, I was running ECLiPSe and neglected to check with SICStus, sorry. Unfortunately, for/4 is not a predicate in itself (it is part of the do/2 predicate), so you can't simply copy it and add it to your SICStus. I'll edit my answer and add a workaround.

Comment: yeh but **how to do that ?** because i find for/3  and i amend it as follows ; `for1(Int, Int, _Lower,_Dec).
for1(Int, Upper, Lower ,Dec) :- Lower < Upper,
                           Next is Upper + Dec, 
                           for1(Int, Next, Lower,Dec).`  but the problem remains unsolved due to **[DO]**

Answer (score 2):

First, your question is about do-loops, a control construct that is found in some systems. The current implementation in SICStus has quite erratic behaviour - in partiular w.r.t. `count`:

```
| ?- for(I,5,1), foreach(I,List) do true.
List = [] ? ;
no
| ?- count(I,5,1), foreach(I,List) do true.
**LOOPS**
```

The documentation is not clear about this looping. But from what I guess, `count` will always count upwards and expects that the `Max` value is legal ; and if not, it loops.

In any case, there are far too many such "features" in do-loops that are still unfixed since many years, that you may want to learn Prolog without do-loops first. In particular, consider higher-order constructs like [`maplist/2..`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868) instead.

Comment: thnx for your clarification, I use them because loops are almost the same principle as the other language like Java, C which I know
but after a rigorous search I find this doc. web: [link](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/userman/umsroot023.html)
with system TKECLiPse !!
plz help me because I am at the crossroads and I am confused in choosing  a system
 in which I implement my prj (SWI, SICS, GNU Prolog ...)  @false

Comment: @AnsPiter Why did you choose to do your project in Prolog in the first place?

Comment: prolog is a one of the best and fast language in which to express the semantics of other languages and it  gives us both a flexible way to encode both the operational semantics of many high-level formalisms, and this is what I want to do... @ALL

Comment: @AnsPiter: You cannot start using Prolog like that. It is much too different from other languages.

Comment: @false i have knowledge not too bad for semantics and programing language acquired from university and i think that your tips & your expertise can help me