# Element manipulation in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list

```
L = [-n,-b,-s]
```

How do i get a list with

```
L = [n,b,s]
```

Is there a built in predicate to do this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) can handle the recursive part for you, but you have to customize it by declaring what the mapping of a single list element should be like.

```
minus_stripped(-X, X).
```

Sample query:

```
?- maplist(minus_stripped, [-n,-b,-s], Xs).
Xs = [n,b,s].
```