# Prolog: efficiency

Tags: prolog, processing-efficiency

Is there a way in prolog to make the following shorter:

```
rule(prop, [1/2,2/2]).
rule(prop, [1/3,2/3,3/3]).
rule(prop, [1/4,2/4,3/4,4/4]).
rule(prop, [1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5,5/5]).
rule(prop, [1/6,2/6,3/6,4/6,5/6,6/6]).
rule(prop, [1/7,2/7,3/7,4/7,5/7,6/7,7/7]).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code isn't necessarily "shorter" for the case of 6 different rules, but it is more scalable, which is probably what you really mean.

You can break this down as follows. First, a rule that generates one list:

```
list_props(N, N, [N/N]).
list_props(X, N, [X/N|T]) :-
    X >= 1,
    X < N,
    X1 is X + 1,
    list_props(X1, N, T).
```

When you call this, it generates one list of proportions from the first argument to the last with the last argument being the denominator. For example:

```
| ?- list_props(1, 4, L).

L = [1/4,2/4,3/4,4/4] ? a

| ?-
```

Note that you could enforce that `N` be an integer >= 1 using `integer(N)` and conditions, but I was being brief and didn't do that in the above.

You can use this in your top level predicate:

```
rule(prop, L) :-
    between(2, 7, X),
    list_props(1, X, L).
```

Which yields:

```
| ?- rule(prop, L).

L = [1/2,2/2] ? ;

L = [1/3,2/3,3/3] ? ;

L = [1/4,2/4,3/4,4/4] ? ;

L = [1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5,5/5] ? ;

L = [1/6,2/6,3/6,4/6,5/6,6/6] ? ;

L = [1/7,2/7,3/7,4/7,5/7,6/7,7/7] ? ;

(2 ms) no
| ?-
```

Comment: Yes this works great. And thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Why not delegate the responsibility for handling recursion—and getting it right, too?

This answer follows up on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35528279/4609915) by @lurker. We do not cover the entire question, but instead focus on showing how a predicate like `list_props/3` can be defined so that all recursion is delegated to the tried and true  Prolog predicates 
[`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#length), `numlist/2` and [`maplist/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist):

```
:- use_module(library(between), [numlist/2]).
:- use_module(library(lists),   [maplist/3]).
```

To customize the versatile [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915%0A) we define:

```
denom_num_expr(B, A, A/B).
```

Sample query using [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) 4.3.2:

```
| ?- length(_Ds, N), numlist(N, _Ds), maplist(denom_num_expr(N), _Ds, Qs).
N = 1, Qs = [1/1] ? ;
N = 2, Qs = [1/2,2/2] ? ;
N = 3, Qs = [1/3,2/3,3/3] ? ;
N = 4, Qs = [1/4,2/4,3/4,4/4] ? ;
N = 5, Qs = [1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5,5/5] ? ;
N = 6, Qs = [1/6,2/6,3/6,4/6,5/6,6/6] ? ;
N = 7, Qs = [1/7,2/7,3/7,4/7,5/7,6/7,7/7] ? ;
N = 8, Qs = [1/8,2/8,3/8,4/8,5/8,6/8,7/8,8/8] ? ;
N = 9, Qs = [1/9,2/9,3/9,4/9,5/9,6/9,7/9,8/9,9/9] ? ...
```

Comment: Yes, much more elegant way to get `list_prop/3` (+1). For no particular reason other than habit, I tend to use gprolog for little Prolog tasks, which doesn't have `numlist/3`, but `numlist/3` is easy to create.

Comment: We need more common ground! While `numlist/3` is offered by both SWI and SICStus, they offer different modes, IIRC. (With SICStus, we could kick the redundant `length/2` goal.)

Comment: @lurker. I take back my previous statement about "SICStus offering more (usable) modes for `numlist`"; that was wishful thinking.

Comment: @lurker. On the plus side, SICStus has `numlist/2`, which is a clear idiom. I wish it will work someday as a generator when both arguments are unbound, just like above conjunction with `length/2`.