# Extracting element from nested lists

Tags: list, prolog, nested-lists

I know that to extract the third element from a simple list containing four elements such as [1,2,3,4] I would do so as below.

```
third([_,_,E,_], E).
```

I would like to extract the third element from a group of nested lists. For example if I had [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]], I would want an output of [3,7,11].

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess:

```
third([], []) :- !.
third([[_, _, E|_]|Rest], [E|R]) :- third(Rest, R).
```

I know some people dislike cut (`!`), but it sounds enough to me.

---

[update 2016-03-14]

A robuster version:

```
third([], []).
third([Xs|Rest], R) :-
    length(Xs, Len),
    (Len < 3 -> third(Rest, R);
                (Xs = [_, _, E|_],
                 R = [E|R1],
                 third(Rest, R1))).
```

[/update]

Comment: Why use [tag:prolog-cut] here? Is there even a single benefit of doing so?

Comment: Nop. I did it just to make clear the  stop clause. You can ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Arĥimedeςℳontegasppαℭacilhας. What is the advantage of that? All I see right now is that it makes the most general use `third(Xs,Ys)` incomplete.

Comment: @MateuszWesoly Just be careful, ’cause this rule doesn’t support lists with less then three elements.

Comment: @repeat There’s a step clause, and a stop one. I put the cut to mark the stop. What makes this rule incomplete is it doesn’t handle lists with less then three elements.

Comment: `?- third(Xs,_), Xs = [_].` fails, `?- Xs = [_], third(Xs,_).` succeeds! *That's* incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Use the widely available [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682987/prolog-map-procedure-that-applies-predicate-to-list-elements/6683502) like in the following sample query:

```
?- maplist(third, [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]], Xs).
Xs = [3, 7, 11].
```

Answer (score 0):

certainly, the solution of @repeat (`maplist predicat`) is the elegant answer
however, this is a simplest answer :

**version 1 :**

```
third_([], []).
third_([List|Rest], [R|Res]) :-
        third(List, R),
        third_(Rest, Res).
```

**version 2**

```
third_([], []).
third_([[_,_,R,_]|Rest], [R|Res]) :-
        third_(Rest, Res).
```

**test :**

```
| ?- third_(Xs,Res).
Xs = [],
Res = [] ? ;
Xs = [[_A,_B,_C,_D]],
Res = [_C] ? ;
Xs = [[_A,_B,_C,_D],[_E,_F,_G,_H]],
Res = [_C,_G] ? ;
Xs = [[_A,_B,_C,_D],[_E,_F,_G,_H],[_I,_J,_K,_L]],
Res = [_C,_G,_K] ?
```