# Prolog - How to limit variable list length

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

I am having trouble generating all lists that meet certain criteria.

```
city(new_york, 47).
city(chicago, 100).

all_unique([]).
all_unique([H|T]) :- H = [] ; (not(member(H, T)), all_unique(T)).

cities([Head|Tail]) :-
    length(Tail, L),
    L < 2,
    city(Head, _A),
    (Tail = [] ; cities(Tail)).
```

When I issue the query `cities(L)`, I want it to generate all lists of cities with a maximum length of 2 and no repetition. What it does now is return all possible lists and then keep trying lists that obviously don't meet the criteria.

```
?- cities(L).
L = [new_york] ;
L = [chicago] ;
L = [new_york, new_york] ;
L = [new_york, chicago] ;
L = [chicago, new_york] ;
L = [chicago, chicago] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
?-
```

How do I tell Prolog not to try lists that are too long or have repeated items?

Comment: `cities(L) :- findall(City, city(City, _, _), L)`.

Comment: Thanks but I can't use findall. Is there a way to do it without findall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `all_unique/1` is better based on [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif):

```
all_unique([]).
all_unique([E|Es]) :-
   maplist(dif(E), Es),
   all_unique(Es).
```

Based on [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) you can define `cities/1` like this:

```
city_(new_york, 47).
city_(chicago, 100).

city(C) :-
   city_(C, _).

cities(List) :-
   length(Ref, 2),
   append(List, _, Ref),
   all_unique(List),
   maplist(city, List).
```

Sample query:

```
?- cities(Xs).
Xs = [] ;
Xs = [new_york] ;
Xs = [chicago] ;
Xs = [new_york, chicago] ;
Xs = [chicago, new_york] ;
false.                                    % terminates universally
```

Comment: Yeah sorry yours works fine. It just doesn't work with my all_unique. I'm not sure why mine doesn't work. I can't use maplist or dif

Comment: @JoshR. Which Prolog processor are you using?

Comment: I'm using swi-prolog

Comment: @JoshR. Ok, SWI has both `dif/2` and `maplist/2`.

Comment: @CapelliC This whole "can't use XYZ" for programming exercises is so dumb I am struggling to find words to express my feelings about it.