# Lists of N length

Tags: list, prolog

Is it to possible to create `N` elements of `0` array in another way than the following one:

```
makeInitialArray(N, A) :-
   N > 0,
   Nn is N-1,
   makeInitialArray(Nn, B),
   append([0], B, A).
makeInitialArray(0, []).
```

It is a poor way on my eye because of the fact of recurrence. I suppose that will be made to call very often operation like that.

Comment: Recurrence is not something wrong at all .. There may be another way to do it but it would also be based on a recurrence at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple! How? Delegate the "recursive part" to built-in / library predicates!

Based on [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#length), [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)   [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682987/prolog-map-procedure-that-applies-predicate-to-list-elements/6683502), and [`(=)/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dunify.html) define `n_zeroes/2`:

```
:- use_module(library(lists), [maplist/2]).

n_zeroes(N, Zs) :-
   length(Zs, N),
   maplist(=(0), Zs).
```

Sample queries using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
| ?- n_zeroes(10, Zs).
Zs = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ? ;
no
| ?- n_zeroes(N, Zs).
N = 0, Zs = [] ? ;
N = 1, Zs = [0] ? ;
N = 2, Zs = [0,0] ? ;
N = 3, Zs = [0,0,0] ? ;
N = 4, Zs = [0,0,0,0] ? ;
N = 5, Zs = [0,0,0,0,0] ? 
...                             % ...goes on forever and ever...
```