# List diagonals of a matrix in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

How could I get a list of the diagonals of a matrix of size `n*n` in Prolog?

Expected behavior:

```
?- diagonal1([[1,3,2],[4,5,7],[6,8,9]],D1). 
D1=[1,5,9]
?- diagonal2([[1,3,2],[4,5,7],[6,8,9]],D2). 
D2=[2,5,6].
```

(I'm fine with using built-in functions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution with `foldl/4`:

```
extract_element(L, L1, [H|L1]):- 
                length(L1, N1), 
                length(L2, N1), 
                append(L2, [H|_], L).

diagonal1(In, Out):- 
                foldl(extract_element, In, [], Res), 
                reverse(Res,Out).

diagonal2(In, Out):- 
                reverse(In, In2),
                foldl(extract_element, In2, [], Out).
```

Can you see spot the difference in `diagonal1/2` and `diagnal2/2` implementations?

In `diagonal1/2` we returned the result form `foldl/4` in Res variable in reverse order that the desired order so we reverse the result to get the correct list. On the other hand in `diagonal2/2` you understand the way that `foldl/4` works above by reversing the Input list we are able not only to extract the correct elements but now the reversed order returned from `foldl/4` is the correct !!!!

Example:

```
?- diagonal1([[1,3,2],[4,5,7],[6,8,9]],D1).
D1 = [1, 5, 9].

?- diagonal2([[1,3,2],[4,5,7],[6,8,9]],D2).
D2 = [2, 5, 6].
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) and the commonly available `reverse/2`:

```
list_diag1([], []).
list_diag1([[E|_]|Ess], [E|Ds]) :-
    maplist(list_tail, Ess, Ess0),
    list_diag1(Ess0, Ds).

list_tail([_|Es], Es).

list_diag2(Ess,Ds) :-
    maplist(reverse, Ess, Fss),
    list_diag1(Fss, Ds).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- list_diag1([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]], D1).
D1 = [a,e,i].

?- list_diag2([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]], D2).
D2 = [c,e,g].
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the original request says that built-ins are fine, I wanted to figure out a solution that didn't involve explicit indexing of a list, or the use of `findall`, `reverse`, or `append` and came up with this:

```
diag1(Matrix, Diag) :-
    diag1(Matrix, [], Diag).

diag1([], _, []).
diag1([Row|Rows], Fs, [D|Ds]) :-
    front_same_length(Fs, D, Row),
    diag1(Rows, [_|Fs], Ds).

diag2([Row|Rows], Diag) :-
    diag2([Row|Rows], Row, Diag).

diag2([], _, []).
diag2([Row|Rows], [_|Fs], [D|Ds]) :-
    front_same_length(Fs, D, Row),
    diag2(Rows, Fs, Ds).

front_same_length([], D, [D|_]).
front_same_length([_|Xs], D, [_|Rs]) :-
    front_same_length(Xs, D, Rs).
```

The principle here is to use `front_same_length/3` to determine an element at some point inside of a list by using another anonymous list of known length. This yields the following results:

```
| ?- diag1([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], D).

D = [1,5,9]

yes
| ?-  diag2([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], D).

D = [3,5,7]

yes
| ?- diag1(Matrix, Diag).

Diag = []
Matrix = [] ? ;

Diag = [A]
Matrix = [[A|_]] ? ;

Diag = [A,B]
Matrix = [[A|_],[_,B|_]] ? ;

Diag = [A,B,C]
Matrix = [[A|_],[_,B|_],[_,_,C|_]] ? ;
...

| ?- diag2(Matrix, Diag).

Diag = [A]
Matrix = [[A]] ? ;

Diag = [A]
Matrix = [[_,A]] ? ;

Diag = [A,B]
Matrix = [[_,A],[B|_]] ? ;

Diag = [A]
Matrix = [[_,_,A]] ? ;

Diag = [A,B]
Matrix = [[_,_,A],[_,B|_]] ? ;

Diag = [A,B,C]
Matrix = [[_,_,A],[_,B|_],[C|_]] ? ;

Diag = [A]
Matrix = [[_,_,_,A]] ? ;
...
```

It seems well-behaved for matrices whose number of rows is less than or equal to the number of columns based upon the way it's designed. It will simply fail if the number of rows exceeds the number of columns.

---

Here's an updated solution that works for a general n x m matrix at the expense of leaving a choice point:

```
diag1(Matrix, Diag) :-
    diag1(Matrix, [], Diag).

diag1([], _, []).
diag1([Row|Rows], Fs, [D|Ds]) :-
    front_same_length(Fs, D, Row),
    diag1(Rows, [_|Fs], Ds).
diag1([Row|_], Fs, []) :-
    same_length(Row, Fs).

diag2([Row|Rows], Diag) :-
    diag2([Row|Rows], Row, Diag).

diag2([], _, []).
diag2([Row|Rows], [_|Fs], [D|Ds]) :-
    front_same_length(Fs, D, Row),
    diag2(Rows, Fs, Ds).
diag2([_|_], [], []).

front_same_length([], D, [D|_]).
front_same_length([_|Xs], D, [_|Rs]) :-
    front_same_length(Xs, D, Rs).

same_length([], []).
same_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :-
    same_length(Xs, Ys).
```

Running sample queries:

```
| ?- diag1([[a,b],[c,d]], D).

D = [a,d] ? ;

no
| ?- diag2([[a,b],[c,d]], D).

D = [b,c] ? a

no
| ?- diag1([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]], D).

D = [a,e,i] ? ;

no
| ?- diag2([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]], D).

D = [c,e,g] ? ;

no
| ?- diag1([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]], D).

D = [a,e] ? a

no
| ?- diag2([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]], D).

D = [c,e] ? ;

no
| ?- diag1([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i],[j,k,l]], D).

D = [a,e,i] ? ;

no
| ?- diag2([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i],[j,k,l]], D).

D = [c,e,g] ? ;

no
| ?-
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic solution using no built in predicates (except `length/2`) could be:

```
isSquare([H|T]):-
    length(H,V),
    length([H|T],V).

diagonal(M,D):-
    diagonalA(M,D,1).

diagonalA([],[],_).
diagonalA([H|T],[HD|TD],I):-
    diagonalInner(H,HD,I,1),
    I1 is I+1,
    diagonalA(T,TD,I1).

diagonalInner([H|_],H,I,I):-!.
diagonalInner([_|T],H,I,I1):-
    I2 is I1+1,
    diagonalInner(T,H,I,I2).

antidiagonal([H|T],A):-
    length(H,N),
    antidiagonalA([H|T],A,N).

antidiagonalA([],[],0).
antidiagonalA([H|T],[HA|TA],N):-
    antidiagonalInner(H,HA,N,1),
    N1 is N-1,
    antidiagonalA(T,TA,N1).

antidiagonalInner([H|_],H,I,I):-!.
antidiagonalInner([_|T],H,I,E):-
    E1 is E+1,
    antidiagonalInner(T,H,I,E1).

solve(M,D1,D2):-
    isSquare(M),
    diagonal(M,D1),
    antidiagonal(M,D2).

?- solve([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],D1,D2).
D1 = [1, 5, 9],
D2 = [3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

**findall/3** and other may be usefull :

```
diagonales(Matrix, [L1, L2]) :-
    length(Matrix, N),
    findall(B, (between(1,N, I), nth1(I, Matrix, Row), nth1(I, Row, B)), L1),
    findall(B, (between(1,N,I), J is N+1-I, nth1(I, Matrix, Row), nth1(J,Row,B)),L2).
```

Comment: `diagonales([[A]], [[1], [2]]).` incorrectly succeeds

Answer (score 1):

```
diag(M,D) :- findall(V, (nth1(I,M,X),nth1(I,X,V)), D).
gaid(M,G) :- length(M,L), findall(V, (nth1(I,M,X),J is L-I+1,nth1(J,X,V)), G).
```