# How to specify a predicate as parameter to another in prolog?

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

I want to write a prolog predicate that holds if the predicate appearing as first parameter holds for all elements of the list appering in second parameter. Here is something that I have tried:

```
?- listing(all).
all(pred(_), [A|B]) :-
    pred(A),
    all(pred(_), B).
all(pred(_), [x]) :-
    pred(x).
```

Something like the following should return true. Is this possible in Prolog?

```
all(number, [3, 5 ,7]).
```

Comment: [`maplist(number,[3,5,7])`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868)

Comment: @false if I add a fact like `maplist(variable, [x, y, z, t]).` does it add a `variable/1` predicate (that holds for `x`,`y`,`z` and `t` atoms) to the knowledge base? Can you point me to some information that can help me concisely write predicates which hold for a given list of atoms?

Comment: that  fact is a definition of a new predicate named `maplist`. probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`call/n`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2):

```
call(X, Y).
```

Given `X=number`, and `Y` is for example `3`, it will call `number(3)`. In case `X` is a term, like `number(1)`, it calls it like `number(1, 3)`, as if the predicate was "*curried*".

So you can implement your function as:

```
all(_, []).
all(P, [A|B]) :-
    call(P, A),
    all(P, B).
```

although for more efficient backtracking, it might be better to swap the parameters:

```
all(P, L) :-
    all2(L, P).

all2([], _).
all2([A|B], P) :-
    call(P, A),
    all2(B, P).
```

But the predicate you here aim to implement already exists in some popular Prolog interpreters [**`maplist/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=apply%3Amaplist/2).

This will call the `Goal` on all elements of the list, or fail if the predicate fails at some point.

You can also construct functors with [**`(=..)/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2). For example:

```
X =.. [number, 1, 3]
```

will result in `X = number(1, 3)`. You can then use call [**`call/1`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/1) with the constructed functor to call the functor as if it was a predicate, like:

```
X =.. [number, 1, 3], call(X).
```

Note that the `(=..)/2` predicate does not work with this "currying" of functors, for example:

```
?- X =.. [number(1), 3].
ERROR: Type error: `atom' expected, found `number(1)' (a compound)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [8] _6428=..[number(1),3]
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

.

Comment: `(=..)/2` does not provide the same functionality as ``call/2` does.

Comment: @false: No I agree, it constructs a functor, it does not *call* the functor, nor does it perform "currying". It can however be usefull if the functor should contain more than seven arguments, since for example SWI-Prolog has no call with eight or nine parameters. Where do I give the impression that it does that?

Comment: Here: *You can also construct functors with (=..)/2 ... simply call call/1* this creates the impression that this is *also* a way to get the same results. Further it does not handle modules.