# Struggling to use Prolog's maplist/2 like a functional mapping function

Tags: prolog, mapping, meta-predicate

I'm using SWI-prolog and I'm trying to create a helper-function that will map over a list and multiply each element with a given integer. My intention is to create a predicate that corresponds to the Haskell function `multByN x n = x * n` and use it in this sense:

`map (multByN 3) [1,2,3]` which would multiply all elements by 3 and yield `[3,6,9]`

I searched for the corresponding predicate in Prolog and found `maplist/2` however I've only been able to use it to check whether boolean conditions hold for each element in a list rather than actually returning a new, processed list. I understand how this works:

`isEven(X) :- 0 is X mod 2`

`maplist(isEven, [2,4,6])` gives `true`.

However, I don't understand how one would do something like `maplist(multByN(3), [1,2,3])` to actually unify some variable with `[3,6,9]`. Since I could not figure this out I tried implementing my own mapping function that maps my predicate `multByN` to a list and I'm getting something that sort of looks right, but that really isn't. I've got this:

```
multByN(X, N, Y) :- Y is N*X.

mapFunc(_, [], L) :-
    write(L), nl.

mapFunc(N, [H|T], L) :-
    multByN(H, N, Z),
    mapFunc(N, T, [Z|L]).
```

Using this predicate I get:

```
?- mapFunc(3, [1,2,3], X).
[9,6,3|_1746]
true ;
```

Here I'm actually printing the final list to see what it looks like, but we can see that the query doesn't actually say `X = [9,6,3|_1746]` so I haven't actually unified anything, as far as I'm aware, I've only just printed it - and that's not what I what.
Another problem here is the uninstantiated variable `_1746` that I want to get rid of, especially since when I try reversing the list I get endless answers and uninstantiated variables.

Ideally, I would like find out both how to solve the problem using `maplist/2` and my own predicate, however I would assume others would be more interested in learning how to use `maplist/2` and that would be more than enough for me.

Comment: "`map (multByN 3) [1,2,3]` would multiply all elements by 3 and yield [3,6,9]" ... yield *where*? Prolog's predicates use their *arguments* to accept and return values, so, we just need one more argument, as is said in the answer by @false.

Comment: Running `map (multByN 3) [1,2,3]` in the haskell compiler GHCI would yield [3,6,9], if that's what you were asking @WillNess

Comment: I wasn't asking, but *suggesting*. :) Evaluation-based languages' functions *return* values, Prolog predicates *determine* values of their arguments. Haskell's `let r = foo x in ...` is`foo(x,r), ...` in Prolog.

Comment: @David Tonhofer. Got a 404 wit ur link... xs permissions 4 all ok?

Comment: @repeat Oh yeah, sorry about that, I cleaned up this afternoon. Here its now: [`maplist/2`](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/maplist/maplist_2_examples.md)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make `maplist(multByN(3), [1,2,3])` work, you need an extra variable. Thus `maplist(multByN(3), [1,2,3], Ys)`.

`maplist(P_2, Xs, Ys)` adds two further arguments one `X` and one `Y` to `P_2`. So `multByN(3)` needs two extra arguments, like

```
multByN(N, X, Y) :-
   Y is N*X.

?- maplist(multByN(3), [1,2,3], Ys).
   Ys = [3,6,9].
```

There are some [more maplists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868) which roughly correspond to their functional cousins.