# Using maplist/2,3,4

Tags: prolog

I'm doing a Prolog project for uni that's based on the Kakuro game.

I'm having trouble with the predicate `spaces_puzzle/2` that does the following:

- Receives the Puzzle in the form of a list of lists that represents each file of the puzzle:

```
  [[[sum_vertical, sum_horizontal], P11, P12, [sum_vertical, sum_horizontal],P13, P14...],
   [[sum_vertical, sum_horizontal], P21, P22, P23, P24, ...],
   [[sum_vertical, sum_horizontal], P31, P32, P33, P34, P35 ...],
   ...]
```

- and returns a list like this `[space(sum_horizontal, [P11,P12]),  space(sum_horizontal, [P13,P14]), space(sum_horizontal, [P21,P22,P23,P24]) ...]`

I was thinking of using a `maplist` with a predicate that I have already defined as `spaces_in_file/3` which will read a list like `[[sum_vertical, sum_horizontal], P11, P12, [sum_vertical, sum_horizontal],P13, P14...]` and output in the wanted formatting: `[space(sum_horizontal, [P11,P12]), space(sum_horizontal, [P13,P14])...]`

I don't understand the syntax for the predicate. The "Goal" I want is the `spaces_in_file/3`. `spaces_in_file(H_V, File, Spaces)` is a simple `bagof` where `H_V` is a character that says which of the sums I should use, `File` is the file I want to check for the spaces, and `Spaces` is my output.

So should it be something like this:

```
spaces_puzzle(Puzzle, Spaces):-
     maplist(spaces_in_file(h, File, Spaces), Puzzle, File)
```

I want my file to be one of the lists of the Puzzle. I can't seem to get the syntax right.

For now I just want the correct Result for the files, I can easily adapt to get the columns with the `transpose/2` predicate which is suggested by the professors.

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: The first argument of [`maplist/2,3...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/772868) is not a proper goal but rather an *incomplete* goal which lacks further arguments that will be supplied element-wise by the lists of the remaining arguments.

Comment: Should my maplist be like this:

maplist(spaces_file, horizontal, Puzzle, Files), ?

Answer (score 0):

`maplist/N` takes a functor and some lists, and checks whether for each element in each list, the predicate named as that functor and with arguments from those lists, is true (you can fix some arguments by adding them to the functor), so e.g:

```
maplist( append, [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], [[2, 4], [5], [6, 7]], List).
```

is equivalent to the conjunction

```
append( [1],       [2, 4], _A1 ),  List = [ _A1 | _T1 ],
append( [1, 2],    [5],    _A2 ),  _T1  = [ _A2 | _T2 ],
append( [1, 2, 3], [6, 7], _A3 ),  _T2  = [ _A3 | _T3 ],  _T3 = [].
```

which will return:

```
%%  List  =  [ _A1, _A2, _A3 ]
List = [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]].
```

Your predicate `spaces_in_file` takes three arguments, `H_V`, `Line` and `Spaces`, you can do a `maplist` by fixing `H_V` and then giving `Line` and `Spaces` to `maplist` as arguments, i.e:

```
maplist( spaces_in_file(h), Lines, Spaces)
```

Comment: I've made some tweaks; feel free to revert! :)

Comment: No, sure, thx. It becomes more explanatory xD